# How does /usr/bin/env know which program to use?

Tags: environment-variables, python

When I use the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python` to run a script, how does the system know which `python` to use?  if I look for a `python` bin path in the environment variables I find nothing.

```
env | grep -i python
```

Comment: oh i think i figured it out- it just searches your $PATH for 'python'

Comment: I've wondered about that too. And why /usr/bin/env? as opposed to /bin/env or env, if it is just getting a list of paths from env?

Comment: Just 'env' won't work because it has to be full path. The 'env' program is usually found in /user/bin/env. On some distros it may also be found as /bin/env, but it's safer to go with /usr/bin/env.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The shebang expects a full path to the interpreter to use so the following syntax would be incorrect:

```
#!python
```

Setting a full path like this might work:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
```

but would be non portable as python might be installed in `/bin`, `/opt/python/bin`, or wherever other location.

Using `env`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

is a method allowing a portable way to specify to the OS a full path equivalent to the one where `python` is first located in the `PATH`.

Answer (score 87):

The [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line (from “sharp bang”, i.e. `#!`) is processed by the kernel. The kernel doesn't want to know about environment variables such as `PATH`. So the name on the shebang line must be an absolute path to an executable. You can also specify an additional argument to pass to that executable before the script name (with system-dependent restrictions I won't go into here). For example, for a Python script, you can specify

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

on the first line, and when you execute the script, the kernel will in fact execute `/usr/bin/python /path/to/script`. But that's not convenient: you need to specify the full path of the command. What if you have `python` in `/usr/bin` on some machines and `/usr/local/bin` on others? Or you want to set your `PATH` to `/home/joe/opt/python-2.5/bin` so as to use a specific version of Python? Since the kernel won't do the `PATH` lookup for you, the idea is to make the kernel run a command that in turns looks up the desired interpreter in the `PATH`:

```
#!/fixed/path/to/path-lookup-command python
```

That `path-lookup-command` must take the name of an executable as an argument and look it up in `PATH` and execute it: the kernel will run `/fixed/path/to/path-lookup-command python /path/to/script`. As it happens, the [`env`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/env.html) command does just that. Its main purpose is to run a command with a different environment, but since it looks up the command name in `$PATH`, it's perfect for our purpose here.

Although this is not officially guaranteed, historic Unix systems provided `env` in `/usr/bin`, and modern systems have kept that location precisely because of the widespread use of `#!/usr/bin/env`. So, in practice, the way to specify that a script must be executed by the user's favorite Python interpreter is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Comment: which one is preferred between `env` and `which`? since which will also get the most eligible executable from my PATH environment.

Comment: @NikhilMulley `which` finds the executable and prints its path. `env` finds the program specified by the first argument and executes it, passing it the remaining arguments.

Comment: so is it that `env` is an eval version of `which` essentially.

Comment: Does `which python` always yield equal results to `#!/usr/bin/env python` ? It appears the answer is *no*. In that case, my question is: how can we programmatically determine what will be executed by any particular shebang?

Comment: @luckman212 https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then

Answer (score 9):

Right, so run:

```
env | grep PATH
```

Your $PATH is a list of directories. Unix will go through that list of directories, in order, until it finds "python".

You can see which directory it finds with the 'which' command:

```
which python
```

Comment: Interestingly, I'm seeing a difference in the python `sys.path` between an activated env `$ env python3`  (`['', '/home/user/test', '/usr/lib/python3.4', '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload', '/home/user/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']`) and `./env/bin/python3` `(['', '/home/user/test', '/usr/lib/python3.4', '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload', '/home/user/test/env3/lib/python3.4/site-packages']`).