# Why is it better to use "#!/usr/bin/env NAME" instead of "#!/path/to/NAME" as my shebang?

Tags: shell-script, shebang

I notice that some scripts which I have acquired from others have the shebang `#!/path/to/NAME` while others (using the same tool, NAME) have the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env NAME`.

Both seem to work properly.  In tutorials (on Python, for example), there seems to be a suggestion that the latter shebang is better.  But, I don't quite understand why this is so.

I realize that, in order to use the latter shebang, NAME must be in the PATH whereas the first shebang does not have this restriction.

Also, it appears (to me) that the first would be the better shebang, since it specifies precisely where NAME is located.  So, in this case, if there are multiple versions of NAME (e.g., /usr/bin/NAME, /usr/local/bin/NAME), the first case specifies which to use.

My question is why is the first shebang preferred to the second one?

Comment: See [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12751/6761)...

Comment: @TheGeeko61: In my case I had something broken and some variables wasn't in env. So I suggest to use this shebang to verify if env is correctly loaded.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

### Objective Criteria/Requirements:

In determining whether to use an ***absolute***
or ***logical*** (`/usr/bin/env`) path to an interpreter in a shebang,
there are two key considerations:

a) *The **interpreter*** can be found on the target system

b) *The **correct version** of the **interpreter***
can be found on the target system

If we **AGREE** that "**b)**" is desirable, ***we also agree that***:

c) It's preferable our scripts ***fail*** rather than execute using an incorrect interpreter version and potentially achieve inconsistent results.

If we **DON'T AGREE** that "**b)**" matters, then any interpreter found will suffice.

### Testing:

Since using a ***logical*** path — `/usr/bin/env` to the interpreter in the shebang — is the most extensible solution allowing the same script to execute successfully on target hosts with different paths to the same interpreter, we'll test it — using Python, due to its popularity — to determine whether it meets our criteria.

1. Does `/usr/bin/env` live in a predictable, consistent location on **POPULAR** (not "*every*") operating systems? ***Yes***:

   - RHEL 7.5
   - Ubuntu 18.04
   - Raspbian 10 ("Buster")
   - OSX 10.15.02
2. Below Python script executed both inside and outside of virtual envelopes (***Pipenv*** used) during tests:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env pythonX.x
   import sys
   print(sys.version)
   print('Hello, world!')
   ```
3. The shebang in the script was varied
   by the Python version number desired
   (all installed on the same host):

   - `#!/usr/bin/env python2`
   - `#!/usr/bin/env python2.7`
   - `#!/usr/bin/env python3`
   - `#!/usr/bin/env python3.5`
   - `#!/usr/bin/env python3.6`
   - `#!/usr/bin/env python3.7`
4. Expected results:
   that `print(sys.version)` = `env pythonX.x`. 
   Each time `./test1.py` was executed using a different installed Python version, the correct version specified in the shebang was printed.
5. Testing Notes:

   - Tests were exclusively limited to Python
   - Perl, like Python,
     [**MUST** live in `/usr/bin` according to the FHS](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s04.html)
   - I've not tested every possible combination on every possible number of Linuxy/Unixy Operating System and version of each Operating System.

### Conclusion:

Although it's TRUE that `#!/usr/bin/env python`
will use the first version of Python it matches in the user's Path,
we can enforce an express preference by specifying a version number
such as `#!/usr/bin/env pythonX.x`. 
Indeed, developers don't care which interpreter is found "*first*";
all they care about is that their code is executed using the specified interpreter they know to be compatible with their code
to ensure consistent results —
*wherever that may live in the filesystem*...

In terms of portability/flexibility, using a ***logical*** — `/usr/bin/env` — rather than ***absolute*** path not only meets requirements a), b) & c) from my testing with different versions of **Python**, but also has the benefit of fuzzy-logic finding the same version interpreter even if they live at different paths on different Operating Systems. 
[And although **MOST** distros respect the FHS, not all do](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard#FHS_compliance).

So, where a script will **FAIL** if the binary lives in a different ***absolute*** path than specified in the shebang,
the same script using a ***logical*** path **SUCCEEDS**
as it keeps going until it finds a match,
thereby offering greater reliability & extensibility across platforms.

Comment: Excellent analysis. We appreciate it.

Comment: The question wasn't specific to Python. I don't think you can safely assume that other interpreters will be installed as, for example `interpX` *and* `interpX.x`. For example, the system I'm using at the moment has `perl`, `perl5.26.3`, and `perl5.30.1`. Another has `perl` and `perl5.26.1`. Neither has a `perl5` command. Also, you didn't mention where  the `pythonX` and `pythonX.x` interpreters on any of the systems you tested were installed. If they were all in `/usr/bin` then your experiment doesn't demonstrate any advantage of `#!/usr/bin/env pythonX.x` over `#!/usr/bin/pythonX.x`.

Comment: @KeithThompson Chose Python for example due to it's huge popularity. The other answers were general and I wanted to take a more practical approach to answering the question.  As specifically relates to Perl- I note in my updated answer (responding to your valid concerns) in "Testing">"Notes"- this too must live in `/usr/bin` according to the FHS.  Although I though it was implied in my answer, added a pp in Conclusions that where both options would yield same result the ***logical*** path has added benefit of offering greater reliability where binaries might live in diff paths on diff systems

Comment: Note that not every Linux system complies to the FHS, not by a long shot. And, paraphrasing the old saying, "Not all the world is Linux". Many Unix(y) systems have Python, Perl, even bash or tcsh as "optional, unsupported third party additions", presumably under `/usr/local` or `/opt/*packagename*` or some really exotic placements.

Comment: **UPVOTED** for the **_formatting_** alone, never mind the _very_ **useful** answer.

Comment: @TeemuLeisti I try to save other technologists the effort of solving the same problems I bump into.  So it's nice to hear somebody found my solution useful, especially when it's involved a fair amount of testing & documentation such as this one has. Most obliged for your kind words!

Comment: As someone mentioned, running scripts in a development environment that is dynamically created in users home, you might run the wrong interpreter.  So then you should use `env` solution.  (see python and ocaml for examples of languages like that).

Answer (score 629):

It isn't necessarily better.

The advantage of `#!/usr/bin/env python` is that it will use whatever `python` executable appears first in the user's `$PATH`.

The *disadvantage* of `#!/usr/bin/env python` is that it will use whatever `python` executable appears first in the user's `$PATH`.

That means that the script could behave differently depending on who runs it.  For one user, it might use the `/usr/bin/python` that was installed with the OS.  For another, it might use an experimental `/home/phred/bin/python` that doesn't quite work correctly.

And if `python` is only installed in `/usr/local/bin`, a user who doesn't have `/usr/local/bin` in `$PATH` won't even be able to run the script.  (That's probably not too likely on modern systems, but it could easily happen for a more obscure interpreter.)

By specifying `#!/usr/bin/python` you specify exactly which interpreter will be used to run the script *on a particular system*.

Another potential problem is that the `#!/usr/bin/env` trick [doesn't let you pass arguments to the intrepreter](http://www.in-ulm.de/%7Emascheck/various/shebang/#splitting) (other than the name of the script, which is passed implicitly).  This *usually* isn't an issue, but it can be.  Many Perl scripts are written with `#!/usr/bin/perl -w`, but `use warnings;` is the recommended replacement these days.  Csh scripts should use `#!/bin/csh -f` -- but csh scripts are [not recommended](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/) in the first place.  But there could be other examples.

I have a number of Perl scripts in a personal source control system that I install when I set up an account on a new system.  I use an installer script that modifies the `#!` line of each script as it installs it in my `$HOME/bin`.  (I haven't had to use anything other than `#!/usr/bin/perl` lately; it goes back to times when Perl often wasn't installed by default.)

A minor point: the `#!/usr/bin/env` trick is arguably an abuse of the `env` command, which was originally intended (as the name implies) to invoke a command with an altered environment.  Furthermore, some older systems (including SunOS 4, if I recall correctly) didn't have the `env` command in `/usr/bin`.  Neither of these is likely to be a significant concern.  `env` does work this way, a lot of scripts do use the `#!/usr/bin/env` trick, and OS providers aren't likely to do anything to break it.  It *might* be an issue if you want your script to run on a really old system, but then you're likely to need to modify it anyway.

Another possible issue, (thanks to Sopalajo de Arrierez for pointing it out in comments) is that cron jobs run with a restricted environment. In particular, `$PATH` is typically something like `/usr/bin:/bin`. So if the directory containing the interpreter doesn't happen to be in one of those directories, even if it's in your default `$PATH` in a user shell, then the `/usr/bin/env` trick isn't going to work. You can specify the exact path, or you can add a line to your crontab to set `$PATH` (`man 5 crontab` for details).

Kevin's comment points out that Python's `virtualenv` creates a special case, where the environment installs a Python interpreter in a special directory that's inserted at the front of `$PATH`. For that particular environment (and perhaps others like it), the `#!/usr/bin/env python` trick (or `python3`?) is likely to be the best solution. (I haven't used virtualenv myself.)

Comment: If /usr/bin/perl is perl 5.8, $HOME/bin/perl is 5.12, and a script requiring 5.12 hardcodes /usr/bin/perl in the shebangs, it can be a major pain to run the script.  I've rarely seen having /usr/bin/env perl grab perl from the PATH be a problem, but it is often very helpful.  And it is much prettier than the exec hack!

Comment: @WilliamPursell: What happens when someone else who doesn't have your `$HOME/bin` in their `$PATH` tries to run the script?

Comment: @Keith  They cannot run it, but since the script is in $HOME/bin, it's not a problem.  If you have privileges to put the script in /usr/bin, then you can upgrade /usr/bin/perl (although that's probably a bad idea.)    I've been on boxes where I wanted to install a fairly large package of perl scripts that hard coded /usr/bin/perl in $HOME, did not have root, and had to go through the entire package modifying the shebang.  I was most unhappy.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: You could always write a Perl script to replace the shebangs for you!

Comment: IIRC SunOS 4 had `/bin` symlinked to `/usr/bin`. I don't have access to a machine to check, but there are several `#!/usr/bin/env perl` scripts with SunOS 4 support on the web, so I think SunOS 4 does have `/usr/bin/env`. On the other hand, SunOS 3 probably didn't. Also, IIRC, NeXTSTEP didn't have `/bin/env`. [Sven Mascheck](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/#env) mentions Unicos and SCO OpenServer.

Comment: It's worth noting that, if you want to use a specific interpreter version, /usr/bin/env is still better. simply because there usually _are_ multiple interpreter versions installed on your machine named perl5, perl5.12, perl5.10, python3.3, python3.32, etc. and if your app has only been tested on that specific version, you can still specify #!/usr/bin/env perl5.12 and be okay even if the user has it installed somewhere unusual. In my experience, 'python' is usually just a symlink to the system standard version (not necessarily the most recent version on the system).

Comment: @root: For Perl, `use v5.12;` serves *some* of that purpose. And `#!/usr/bin/env perl5.12` will fail if the system has Perl 5.14 but not 5.12. For Python 2 vs. 3, `#!/usr/bin/python2` and `#!/usr/bin/python3` are likely to work.

Comment: The reasoning in this answer is so bad I don't even know where to begin.  Of course you want to respect the user's PATH!.  You can't possibly know which interpreter to use.

Comment: @GoodPerson: Suppose I write a Perl script to be installed in `/usr/local/bin`. I happen to know that it works correctly with `/usr/bin/perl`. I have *no idea* whether it works with whatever `perl` executable some random user happens to have in his or her `$PATH`. Maybe somebody is experimenting with some ancient version of Perl; because I specified `#!/usr/bin/perl`, my script (which the user doesn't necessarily even know or care is a Perl script) won't stop working.

Comment: You also have no idea if it works with the perl in /usr/bin/perl - it may be a different version.  What if the perl version in /usr/bin/perl is updated?   What if the user doesn't even have /usr/bin/perl (and instead, more likely, has /usr/local/bin/perl).  What if the version of perl in /usr/bin is completely broken and the user has a patched version in ~/opt/bin?  Respecting the user's PATH is more correct.


If you write code for one very specific never changing system, I could see you relying on the quirks of the system.  Otherwise, it is best to be portable

Comment: If it doesn't work with `/usr/bin/perl`, I'll find out very quickly, and it's the system owner/administrator's responsibility to keep it up to date. If you want to run my script with your own perl, feel free to grab and modify a copy or invoke it via `perl foo`. (And you might consider the possibility that the 55 people who upvoted this answer also know a thing or two. It's certainly possible that you're right and they're all wrong, but that's not the way I'd bet.)

Comment: This answer is not congruent with how Python in particular is commonly used.  The Python executable you want to use is *rarely* `/usr/bin/python`.  Typically, the one you want lives in a [Virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/), and is at the front of the user's `$PATH`.  In the rare situations where that is *not* the case, `/usr/bin` will usually be on the user's `$PATH` anyway.

Comment: @Kevin: Hmm. I'm not much of a Python programmer myself, but I find your statement surprising. I would have thought that most users of Python scripts (not necessarily Python *programmers*) don't even use Virtualenv. On the other hand, I suppose the `#!/usr/bin/env` hack would still work for such users -- but it wouldn't have much advantage over `#!/usr/bin/python`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Most uses of Python are in servers.  Those uses require isolation and must not interfere with each other.  Because of the highly dynamic nature of Python, this isolation becomes very important and cannot be relegated to the OS level.  You may have multiple separate web applications running on Python, and they may have totally disjoint support situations (e.g. one only runs on 2.x and one only runs on 3.x).  The Windows version of Python [explicitly supports the `/usr/bin/env` hack](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/).

Comment: @Kevin: Just one small point: I've never seen `/usr/bin/python` be a Python 3 executable; that's generally `/usr/bin/python3`. (Unless some newer distributions have changed that -- which would break a lot of scripts.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: Arch did and it [broke everything](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/).

Comment: @Kevin: What exactly it broke? Considering it still points to python3, it all went well.

Comment: @x-yuri: Presumably it would break every Python2 script that uses `#!/usr/bin/python` and invokes `print` without parentheses. I don't use Arch, so I can't say how many problems it's actually caused.

Comment: I've been using it about 5 years. Didn't have any python issues yet.

Comment: One point of interest that I've run into is when pointing an interpreter at a script versus executing the script directly. Example: in my environment, my path loads `/Applications/XAMPP/bin/php`, so if I run `php someTestScript.php`, it will be run by the XAMPP php everytime, but if I use  `./someTestScript.php` and the shebang is set to `#!/usr/bin/php`, the script is executed by `/usr/bin/php`. So there can be some confusion (from a user standpoint) regarding why a script has different output based on `php someTestScript.php` vs `./someTestScript.php`

Comment: @Anthony: True -- but not particularly relevant in my experience. The whole point of the `#!` line is that you can invoke the script as an ordinary command; you don't have to *care* whether it's run by php, sh, perl, or it's a binary executable. It's unlikely that I'd type `php someTestScript.php`. But of course other people's habits might differ.

Comment: using `php someTestScript.php` is handy when not wanting to make the file explicitly executable, and when wanting to run it without a shebang (like if you just wanted to confirm what a script outputs or if it throws errors, etc). But many times I've seen scripts that have a shebang line to make them executable (basically so it can get some first-class cred), but documentation will still be mixed on how to execute (some docs using `php someTestScript` others using `./someTestScript`)....

Comment: ... You're right that it shouldn't matter (and obviously, documentation should be better written, etc), but the part of this answer "the script could behave differently depending on who runs it" reminded me of this similar scenario, where a script might run differently than expected (or understood) due to a different interpreter being used.

Comment: What about using the `env` way on CRON tabs?

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez: Um, what about it? If you mean, for example, using `/usr/bin/env python some_script` as a command in a crontab, that's no different than `python some_script`; both the `env` command and the cron daemon use the same `$PATH`.

Comment: Well, I was trying `* * * * * /usr/bin/env bash /path/to/MyScript.sh` on my CronTab, but, even when any `.sh` script that starts by `#!/usr/bin/env bash` seems to work fine, the referred `MyScript.sh` is not executed at all. Possible explanation: my Linux is a Fun_Plug (BusyBox modification) one running on a NAS. The only way to make it work has been `* * * * * /ffp/bin/bash /path/to/MyScript.sh`.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez: The `/usr/bin/env` trick depends on the command being in your `$PATH`. Apparently your system doesn't have `bash` in one of the directories in cron's restricted `$PATH`. Dropping the `/usr/bin/env` would have no effect. But if you edit your script with `#!/ffp/bin/bash`, you can execute it directly: `* * * * * /path/to/MyScript.sh`.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez: I've updated my answer to address your point (see the last paragraph). Thanks!

Comment: +1 for mentioning that `env` doesn't always reside in `/usr/bin` (although it's pretty exotic).

Comment: What is the benfit of env in the shebang vs. only the name of the executable? `#!bash` and isn't this discouraged because you can trick an executable in the $PATH with the same name and isn't the env trick vulnerable to the same exploit?

Comment: @thst `#!bash` is discouraged because it doesn't work. The mechanism that handles the `#!` line doesn't use `$PATH`. (Yes, the `env` trick is vulnerable to exploits -- which can be minimized by not including `.` in your `$PATH`.)

Comment: the first 3 sentences say it all!

Comment: Splitting arguments and passing them to the interpreter works, for example: `#! /usr/bin/env -S bash -c 'nix-shell --pure $0'`. Also shebang is not meant to pickup the exact versions of software. Other tools manage this nowadays, for example Nix, or other sandboxing/containerization tooling.

Comment: @AleXoundOS In my experience the handling of arguments on a `#!` line can vary across systems. On my system, the remainder of the line after the command seems to be treated as a single argument. And those other tools don't do much good if they're not available on the target system.

Comment: @KeithThompson it's a long time later... but I'd definitely second Kevin's comments on python here. If you expect the code to be packaged up in a .rpm or .deb and installed to `/usr/bin` then then `#!/usr/bin/python3` is the way to go.  That's because it's expected to behave as a system utility and use the system interpreter.  But that's pretty much the only time you use the system interpreter.  In (nearly) every other context including [PyPi](https://pypi.org/) you use a virtual environment and you *need* `#!/usr/bin/env python` or the scripts won't install or run correctly.

Comment: @PhilipCouling Thanks, I've added the information from Kevin's comment to my answer.

Comment: Another reason why someone may want to actually *avoid env shebangs* is for security. To execute arbitrary code all a hacker has to do is replace a symlink with a preferred binary of choice. Not only will the `env` command execute but it will be cleverly obfuscated. As an added benefit, all scripts on the system that execute `env` generally will do the same thing.

Comment: @ingyhere I'm not sure what symlink you're talking about. A hacker who can replace `/usr/bin/env` (i.e., has write access to `/usr/bin`) already pretty much owns the system.

Comment: @KeithThompson Not `env` specifically, but bury a binary as a symlink replacement somewhere in the path, even `~/.local/bin`. Loose perms may be an oversight when shared tools are installed.

Comment: @ingyhere If you have a directory in your `$PATH` that can be updated by anyone other than you and `root`, you've already got problems. I'm not convinced that the `env` hack makes those problems much worse.

Answer (score 130):

Because /usr/bin/env can interpret your `$PATH`, which makes scripts more portable.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
```

Will only run your script if python is installed in /usr/local/bin.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Will interpret your `$PATH`, and find python in any directory in your `$PATH`.

So your script is more portable, and will work without modification on systems where python is installed as `/usr/bin/python`, or `/usr/local/bin/python`, or even custom directories (that have been added to `$PATH`), like `/opt/local/bin/python`.

Portability is the only reason using `env` is preferred to hard coded paths.

Comment: Custom directories for `python` executables are particularly common as `virtualenv` usage increases.

Comment: What about  `#! python`, why isn't that used?

Comment: `#! python` isn't used because you'd have to be in the same directory as the python binary, since the bareword `python` is interpreted as the complete path to the file.  If you don't have a python binary in the current directory, you'll get an error like `bash: ./script.py: python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`.  It's the same as if you used `#! /not/a/real/path/python`

Comment: @TimKennedy this is demonstrably false on my system: https://pastebin.com/tjV3yARh

Comment: @JonathanTomer *very* interesting!  what combo of OS and shell is that?  on my Ubuntu 18.04 system with bash, that doesn't work: https://pastebin.com/ynBJmrnw

Comment: @TimKennedy `uname -a` says: Linux silvius 5.6.0-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.6.14-1 (2020-05-23) x86_64 GNU/Linux, and I'm using zsh. zsh is the key: I have the same failure when running from bash, or with `perl -e 'exec "/tmp/foo" or die $!'`. TIL, zsh is doing way more work than it has to.

Comment: @TimKennedy aha, from `man zsh-misc`: "If  execution fails because the file is not in executable format, and the file is not a directory, it is assumed to be a shell script.  /bin/sh is spawned to execute it. If the program is a file beginning with `#!', the remainder of the first line specifies an interpreter for the program. The shell will execute the specified interpreter on operating systems that do not handle this executable format in the kernel." So zsh has implemented its own shebang-line parsing in case it runs on a non-POSIX system, and its implementation differs from Linux kernel's.

Comment: Thanks, @JonathanTomer.  I've never used zsh, but maybe it's time to give it a try.

Comment: @JonathanKlabundeTomer Very interesting. It seems that `zsh` has special code branch that catches the error about `exec()` failing and it will try to workaround that by doing extra magic. I wish the Linux native `exec()` handling were changed to allow shabang to start with non-slash character to execute a binary from `PATH` because trusting `zsh` specific error handling to avoid writing `/usr/bin/env` or absolute path doesn't seem worth the effort. I guess it's too late to fix this, though, because non-absolute path already means relative to script file, not relative to `PATH`.

Answer (score 58):

Specifying the absolute path is more precise on a given system. The downside is that it's too precise. Suppose you realize that the system installation of Perl is too old for your scripts and you want to use your own instead: then you have to edit the scripts and change `#!/usr/bin/perl` to `#!/home/myname/bin/perl`. Worse, if you have Perl in `/usr/bin` on some machines, `/usr/local/bin` on others, and `/home/myname/bin/perl` on yet other machines, then you'd have to maintain three separate copies of the scripts and execute the appropriate one on each machine.

`#!/usr/bin/env` breaks if `PATH` is bad, but so does almost anything. Attempting to operate with a bad `PATH` is very rarely useful, and indicates that you know very little about the system the script is running on, so you can't rely on any absolute path anyway.

There are two programs whose location you can rely on on almost every unix variant: `/bin/sh` and `/usr/bin/env`. Some obscure and mostly retired Unix variants had `/bin/env` without having `/usr/bin/env`, but you're unlikely to encounter them. Modern systems have `/usr/bin/env` precisely because of its widespread use in shebangs. `/usr/bin/env` is something you can count on.

Apart from `/bin/sh`, the only time you should use an absolute path in a shebang is when your script isn't meant to be portable, so you can count on a known location for the interpreter. For example, a bash script that only works on Linux can safely use `#!/bin/bash`. A script that is only meant to be used in-house can rely on house interpreter location conventions.

`#!/usr/bin/env` does have downsides. It's more flexible than specifying an absolute path but still requires knowing the interpreter name. Occasionally you might want to run an interpreter that isn't in the `$PATH`, for example in a location relative to the script. In such cases, you can often make a [polyglot script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66210/how-can-i-have-more-than-one-possibility-in-a-scripts-shebang-line/66242#66242) that can be interpreted both by the standard shell and by your desired interpreter. For example, to make a Python 2 script portable both to systems where `python` is Python 3 and `python2` is Python 2, and to systems where `python` is Python 2 and `python2` doesn't exist:

```
#!/bin/sh
''':'
if type python2 >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then
  exec python2 "$0" "$@"
else
  exec python "$0" "$@"
fi
'''
# real Python script starts here
def …
```

Answer (score 28):

Specifically for perl, using `#!/usr/bin/env` is a bad idea for two reasons.

First, it's not portable.  On some obscure platforms env isn't in /usr/bin.  Second, as [Keith Thompson](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29620/304960) has noted, it can cause trouble with passing arguments on the shebang line.  The maximally portable solution is this:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec perl -x "$0" "$@"
#!perl
```

For details on how it works, see 'perldoc perlrun' and what it says about the -x argument.

Comment: Exactly the anser I was looking for: how to write porable "shebang" for perl script that will allow additional aruments passed to perl (last line in your example accepts additional aruments).

Comment: @AmokHuginnsson it is a bletcherous kludge.

Comment: It is, but it's a bletcherous kludge that *works*. It's a blethcherous kludge that *exists* because less kludgey solutions don't work.

Comment: What if `sh` is not in `/bin`? True story for google distroless containers.

Comment: Yeah, it also won't work if perl isn't in the path, or on an Amiga, or ...

If you're using something weird like that then you're going to have to do some work yourself.

Comment: Many development environments install interpreters of different versions in the users `HOME`.  And one choose which to use by prepending the `PATH` with the selected version.  Look at `python` and `ocaml` for examples of this, there are other examples.

Answer (score 20):

The reason there is a distinction between the two is because of how scripts are executed.

Using `/usr/bin/env` (which, as mentioned in other answers, is not in `/usr/bin` on some OSes) is required because you can't just put an executable name after the `#!` - it must be an absolute path. This is because the `#!` mechanism works on a lower level than the shell. It's part of the kernel's binary loader. This can be tested. Put this in a file and mark it executable:

```
#!bash

echo 'foo'
```

You will find it prints an error like this when you attempt to run it:

```
Failed to execute process './test.sh'. Reason:
The file './test.sh' does not exist or could not be executed.
```

If a file is marked executable and begins with a `#!`, the kernel (which does not know about `$PATH` or the current directory: these are user-land concepts) will look for a file using an absolute path. Because using an absolute path is problematic (as mentioned in other answers), someone came up with a trick: You can run `/usr/bin/env` (which is almost always in that location) to run something using `$PATH`.

Answer (score 16):

There are two more problems with using `#!/usr/bin/env`

1. It doesn't solve the problem of specifying the full path to the interpreter, it just moves it to `env`.

   `env` is no more guaranteed to be in `/usr/bin/env` than `bash` is guaranteed to be in `/bin/bash` or python in `/usr/bin/python`.
2. `env` overwrites ARGV[0] with the name of the interpreter (e..g bash or python).

   This prevents your script's name from appearing in, e.g., `ps` output (or changes how/where it appears) and makes it impossible to find it with, e.g, `ps -C scriptname.sh`

*[update 2016-06-04]*

And a third problem:

3. Changing your PATH is **more** work than just editing the first line of a script, especially when scripting such edits is trivial.  e.g:

   `printf "%s\n" 1 i '#!'$(type -P python2) . w | ed foo.py`

   Appending or pre-pending a directory to $PATH is fairly easy (although you still have to edit a file to make it permanent - your `~/.profile` or whatever - and it's far from easy to script THAT edit because the PATH could be set anywhere in the script, not in the first line).

   Changing the order of PATH directories is significantly more difficult....and far harder than just editing the `#!` line.

   And you still have all the other problems that using `#!/usr/bin/env` gives you.

   @jlliagre suggests in a comment that `#!/usr/bin/env` is useful for testing your script with multiple interpreter versions, "by only changing their PATH / PATH order"

   If you need to do that, it's much easier to just have several `#!` lines at the top of your script (they're just comments anywhere but the very first line) and cut/copy-and-paste the one you want to use now to the first line.

   In `vi`, that would be as simple as moving the cursor to the `#!` line you want, then typing `dd1GP` or `Y1GP`.  Even with an editor as trivial as `nano`, it would take seconds to use the mouse to copy and paste.

---

Overall, the advantages of using `#!/usr/bin/env` are minimal at best, and certainly don't even come close to outweighing the disadvantages.  Even the "convenience" advantage is largely illusory.

IMO, it's a silly idea promoted by a particular kind of programmer who thinks that operating systems are not something to be worked with, they are a **problem** to be worked around (or ignored at best).

PS: here's a simple script to change the interpreter of multiple files at once.

`change-shebang.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

interpreter="$1"
shift

if [ -z "$(type -P $interpreter)" ] ; then
  echo "Error: '$interpreter' is not executable." >&2
  exit 1
fi

if [ ! -d "$interpreter" ] && [ -x "$interpreter" ] ; then
  shebang='#!'"$(realpath -e $interpreter)" || exit 1
else
  shebang='#!'"$(type -P $interpreter)"
fi

for f in "$@" ; do
  printf "%s\n" 1 i "$shebang" . w | ed "$f"
done
```

Run it as, e.g., `change-shebang.sh python2.7 *.py` or `change-shebang.sh $HOME/bin/my-experimental-ruby *.rb`

Comment: Both of these potential issues have already been mentioned in existing answers. In any case, `env` is much more likely to be in `/usr/bin/env` than `bash` or `python` being in any specific location.

Comment: Nobody else here has mentioned the ARGV[0] problem.  And nobody has mentioned the /path/to/env issue in a form that directly addresses one of the arguments for using it (i.e. that bash or perl might be in an unexpected location).

Comment: Sorry, you are right about the argv[0] issue, I was confusing with another thread. Your first point is still questionable. Using `env` in the first place assumes the command to launch is in the user's PATH and is a portable way to publish a script giving it the best opportunity to be executable whatever the target system. If that target command (e.g python, perl) is not in the PATH, there is no portable way to specify it in the script shebang anyway.

Comment: The interpreter path issue is easily fixed by a sysadmin with symlinks, or by the user editing their script.  It's certainly not a significant enough problem to encourage people to put up with the all of the other issues caused by using env on the shebang line that are mentioned here and on other questions.  That's promoting a bad solution in the same kind of way that encouraging `csh` scripting is promoting a bad solution: it kind of works but there are much better alternatives.

Comment: Not everybody is a sysadmin on their machine. The `env` solution is aimed at helping non operating system specialists to copy/paste or download scripts that have a good chance to work as is. It is also one of the methods that allow more advanced users to experiment with multiple unchanged scripts to be executed by custom versions of the target interpreter by only changing their PATH / PATH order (sorry about that too long sentence...)

Comment: non-sysadmins can ask their sysadmin to do it.  or they can simply edit the script and change the `#!` line.

Comment: That is precisely what env is helping to avoid: depending on a sysadmin or OS specific technical knowledge unrelated to python or whatever.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this a thousand times, because it's actually a great answer _either way_ -- if someone uses `/usr/bin/env` and I need to get rid of it locally, or if they didn't use it and I need to add it.  Both cases can occur, and therefore the scripts provided in this answer are a potentially useful tool to have in the toolbox.

Comment: `env is no more guaranteed to be in /usr/bin/env than bash is guaranteed to be in /bin/bash or python in /usr/bin/python` - This seemed right at first but then I thought, what is the likelihood of me or someone else putting `env` in a weird place vs putting `python` in a weird place? I'm much more likely to put `python` in a wacky place, so `env` does seem more predictable to me.

Comment: @xdhmoore, `/usr/bin/env` is dependable, where the heck `python` lives is anybody's guess (most Linux systems have `/usr/bin/python`, on non-Linux systems it is usually an "unsupported addon" buried somewhere funky).

Comment: I wish I could upvote this a thousand times for demonstrating use of ed(1) in a pipeline!

Comment: I fully agree with this answer and I just want to mention that the *real* problem is people writing `/usr/bin/python` instead of `/usr/bin/python2` or `/usr/bin/python3` because those are two different programming languages! The `/usr/bin/python` should have been re-defined to *always* point to python2 compatible version and we wouldn't even have this whole mess. The same with `ruby` – if you make *incompatible variant*, change the name of the interpreter binary, don't mess with the `PATH`.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen unfortunately, it's more complicated than that for python.  python manages to have incompatibilities even within the same major version....and complicated even further by python expecting separate lib directories for each minor version too.  It's like they go out of their way to ensure breakage on every release.

Comment: @cas Oh... I wasn't aware that python is incompatible even between minor versions, too. That's one more reason not to use python for anything important.

Answer (score 12):

Adding another example here:

Using `env` is also useful when you want to share scripts between multiple `rvm` environments for example.

Running this on the cmd line, shows which ruby version will be used when  `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` is used inside a script:

`env ruby --version`

Therefore, when you use `env`, you can use different ruby versions through rvm, without changing your scripts.

Comment: // , Excellent idea. The whole point of multiple interpreters is NOT to break the code, or to have code depend upon _that_ _specific_ _interpreter_.

Comment: Or maybe you could use different interpreter name if you change the language? If you put `env ruby` at the front of your script and you *actually require some specific version*, you're doing it backwards. The `env ruby` should mean *any* version of ruby is okay. Both python and ruby have this same problem where the language syntax or features is different but different people *pretend* to use the same language and use identical shebang.

Answer (score 7):

If you're writing purely for yourself or for your job and the location of the interpreter you're calling is always in the same place, by all means use the direct path.  In all other cases use `#!/usr/bin/env`.

Here's why: in your situation the `python` interpreter was in same place regardless of which syntax you used but for many people it could have installed in a different place.  Though most major programming interpreters are located in `/usr/bin/` a lot of newer software is defaulting to `/usr/local/bin/`.

I would even argue to always use `#!/usr/bin/env` because if you have multiple versions of the same interpreter installed and you don't know what your shell will default to, then you should probably fix that.

Comment: "In all other cases use #!/usr/bin/env" is too strong. // As @KeithThompson and others point out, #!/usr/bin/env means the script can behave differently depending on who/how run.  Sometimes this different behavior can be a security bug.  // For example, NEVER use "#!/usr/bin/env python" for a setuid or setgid script, because  the user invoking the script can place malware in a file called "python" in PATH.  Whether setuid/gid scripts are ever a good idea is a different issue - but certainly, no setuid/gid executable should ever trust the user provided environment.

Comment: @KrazyGlew, you can't setuid a script on Linux. You do it trough an executable. And when writing this executable, it is good practice, and widely done, to clear the environment variables. Some environment variable are also [purposefully ignored](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48549/176127).

Answer (score 7):

For portability and compatiblity reasons it is better to use

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

instead of

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
```

There are multple possiblities, where a binary may be located on an Linux/Unix system. Check the hier(7) manpage for a detailed description of the file system hierarchy.

FreeBSD for example installs all software, which is not part of the base system, in */usr/local/*. Since the bash is not part of the base system, the bash binary is installed at */usr/local/bin/bash*.

When you want a portable bash/csh/perl/whatever script, which runs under most Linux Distributions and FreeBSD, you should use *#!/usr/bin/env*.

Also take note, that most Linux installations have also (hard)linked the env binary to /bin/env or softlinked /usr/bin into /bin which should **not** be used in the shebang. So don't use *#!/bin/env*.

Comment: To paraphrase, "not all the world's a Linux". And not all Linux systems abide by hier(7) either. Most non-Linux systems just don't have bash, or it is a "unsupported, unofficial addon" buried somewhere obscure.

Answer (score 1):

Because this is a very old post, it understandably fails to acknowledge the modern Mac OS/X wherein one ***cannot*** update `/bin/sh` or `/bin/bash` due to Apple's unwillingness to accept the terms of the GPL3 -- even root permissions are insufficient to override this decision in my experience. What this often means is that such scripts may not work at all due the old version of `sh` and/or `bash` that are/is installed by Apple. `</rant>`

Such problems reinforce the value of using `#!/usr/bin/env` discussed at-length above; however, as previously-stated by other respondents, that may not always be a viable solution. That being said, I've been using the following "shebang" in my Perl scripts for many years on many different Unix-like systems:

```
eval '(exit $?0)' && eval 'exec perl -S $0 ${1+"$@"}' #-*-perl-*-
& eval 'exec perl -S $0 $argv:q'
        if 0;
```

- Where `eval '(exit $?0)'` determines if there is a script to execute.
- Where `eval 'exec perl -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'` is used if the user's current shell is `sh`, `bash` or some similar variant that has built-in `eval` and `exec` commands.
- Where `#-*-perl-*-` identifies the script as perl for my preferred Emacs editor.
- Where `eval 'exec perl -S $0 $argv:q'` is used if the user's current shell is `[t]csh` or some similar variant that has built-in `eval` and `exec` commands.

It seems to me that this is easily adapted to execute scripts written in other languages, and just the embedded interpreter needs to be changed accordingly:

```
eval '(exit $?0)' && eval 'exec PREFERRED-INTERPRETER $0 ${1+"$@"}'
& eval 'exec PREFERRED-INTERPRETER $0 $argv:q'
        if 0;
```