# How to find bash in a portable way

Tags: bash

When we write shell scripts we do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

But What if bash is in `/usr/bin/`? How can we find it in a portable way inside script? I did this, but it gives error:

```
#!which bash
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If `bash` is in the different location you can hash bang it as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Location for `env` is pretty standard across the variants.

Comment: A similar arabesque is useful for python scripts:  `#!/usr/bin/env python`

Comment: `python`, `perl` and all other scripting languages.

Comment: But this method does have some drawbacks; see [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29608/10454) and [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29620/10454).  Most systems are going to install `bash` as `/bin/bash` (via a symlink if necessary) simply because so many scripts out there have `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: There are drawbacks to using either method but the fact that scripts out there use `#!/bin/bash` doesn't necessarily make them right.