# Environment settings on setuid executables

Tags: environment-variables, dynamic-linking, setuid

I am observing a curious behavior when running a program with `setuid` bit enabled.

Program `foo` is owned by user `bar` with setuid bit set.

User `execbar` runs `foo`

`foo` reports that one of the dynamic libraries is inaccessible.

The dynamic library in question is located in a directory outside the normal `ld.so.conf` search paths so it's set via `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for user `execbar`

The question is:  Is running a program with `setuid` clears the environment set by user `execbar`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, but the dynamic linker will ignore some environment variables when run with setuid as otherwise you could make it load and run any code as the target user. That goes for `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `LD_PRELOAD` and more. See [ld.so(8)](http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man8/ld.so.8.html).