# Which component of linux remove filter environment variables on executing setuid program?

Tags: linux, environment-variables, ld

It's observed that when running a program having setuid bit set, it won't receive some environment variables set on the shell (bash etc.). Several environment variables which get removed this way are `LD_PRELOAD, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, LD_ORIGIN_PATH, LD_DEBUG_OUTPUT, LD_PROFILE, LD_USE_LOAD_BIAS, GCONV_PATH`.

As mentioned in [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=129682) and in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48548/environment-settings-on-setuid-executables), this is the intended behavior. Reason for this is to reduce attack vector.
Manual page of `ld.so (8)` also states this.

The question is, which component of a Linux OS removes environment variables like this?

- Is it the shell?
- Is it a function like `fork()` or `execve()` etc. a shell calls internally when executing a command?
- Is it the `ld.so`?

Note: any answer will be helpful. However, if you can direct me to which resources contain information on this matter, like which manual pages should I read, it would be more helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of these variables are intended for the dynamic linker, or other components of the C library, and it’s the dynamic linker which takes care of removing them when starting setuid binaries. This is documented in [the “ENVIRONMENT” section of `man ld.so`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html#ENVIRONMENT) (for the GNU C library):

> For security reasons, if the dynamic linker determines that a
> binary should be run in secure-execution mode, the effects of
> some environment variables are voided or modified, and
> furthermore those environment variables are stripped from the
> environment, so that the program does not even see the
> definitions.  Some of these environment variables affect the
> operation of the dynamic linker itself, and are described below.
> Other environment variables treated in this way include:
> `GCONV_PATH`, `GETCONF_DIR`, `HOSTALIASES`, `LOCALDOMAIN`, `LOCPATH`,
> `MALLOC_TRACE`, `NIS_PATH`, `NLSPATH`, `RESOLV_HOST_CONF`, `RES_OPTIONS`,
> `TMPDIR`, and `TZDIR`.

The `ld.so`-affecting variables are documented individually:

> This variable is ignored in secure-execution mode.

appears in the documentation for each such variable.

The full list can also be seen [in the GNU C library’s source code](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/generic/unsecvars.h), as can the removal code itself, both [for dynamically-linked binaries](https://sourceware.org/git?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=elf/rtld.c;h=19e328f89e348347c1d0a045fbda1af49b0edc1f;hb=HEAD#l2683) and [for dynamic linking in statically-linked binaries](https://sourceware.org/git?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=elf/dl-support.c;h=153dd57ad2a4746fefe30294ed3fd90e9a9ce57e;hb=HEAD#l304).

Other C libraries’ dynamic linkers behave in a similar fashion, for variables which they care about; for example, [musl documents that](https://musl.libc.org/doc/1.1.24/manual.html)

> This variable is completely ignored in programs invoked setuid, setgid, or with other elevated capabilities.

for a number of variables (`LD_PRELOAD`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `MUSL_LOCPATH`), and that some features of the `TZ` variable aren’t available in such circumstances.