# Specifying a generic interpreter for a program like expect?

Tags: shell-script, executable, interpreter

I am writing expect script which can be used on mulple operating systems but the problem is

i can't use `#!/usr/bin/expect` evreywhere so instead i tried to do

```
 #!`which expect`
```

at the top but it failed

```
[sesiv@itseelm-lx4151 ~]$ ./sendcommand
-bash: ./sendcommand: `which: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

any solution for this.

Comment: Is there anything you can use everywhere, `/bin/bash` e.g.?

Comment: i am not sure about this but, i think most standard OS will have `/bin/sh` say AIX,solaris,linux,redhat,suse,HP

Comment: am i right ? @Hauke

Comment: See also [How can I have more than one possibility in a script's shebang line?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66210/how-can-i-have-more-than-one-possibility-in-a-scripts-shebang-line/66242#66242)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One trick that mostly works (for perl, python, php interpreters, and probably others):

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
```

I think `env` is always in `/usr/bin/`.  A lot of interpreters can run that way now. Other hacks used to exist, but weren't understandable, or weren't all that portable.

Comment: This is also the portable way to run bash (`#!/usr/bin/env bash`, which will work even when your bash is in /usr/bin/local/bash or elsewhere).

Comment: Also, if you want to specify some option to expect, like -f, the following syntax seems to work:
`#! /usr/bin/env -S expect -f` (found this in one of the answers in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63979/shebang-line-with-usr-bin-env-command-argument-fails-on-linux)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest

```
#!/bin/sh
expect_path="$(which expect)"
"$expect_path" "$0" "$@"
```

I hope this works; I am not familiar with the differences between bash and sh.

Comment: You can also expand on this by putting a check that it was actually found, and using *exec* before the path.