# Why not use pathless shebangs?

Tags: shell, shebang

Is it possible to have a shebang that, instead of specifying a path to an interpreter, it has the name of the interpreter, and lets the shell find it through $PATH?

If not, is there a reason why?

Comment: You may find the [Why is it better to use “#!/usr/bin/env NAME” instead of “#!/path/to/NAME” as my shebang?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29608/why-is-it-better-to-use-usr-bin-env-name-instead-of-path-to-name-as-my) discussion interesting.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

PATH lookup is a feature of the standard C library in userspace, as are environment variables in general. The kernel doesn't see environment variables except when it passes over an environment from the caller of [`execve`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exec_(operating_system)) to the new process.

The kernel does not perform any interpretation on the path in `execve` (it's up to wrapper functions such as `execvp` to perform PATH lookup) or in a shebang (which more or less re-routes the `execve` call internally). So you need to put the absolute path in the shebang¹. The [original shebang implementation](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/4.0BSD_newsys_sys1.c.html) was just a few lines of code, and it hasn't been significantly expanded since.

In the first versions of Unix, the shell did the work of invoking itself when it noticed you were invoking a script. Shebang was added in the kernel for several reasons (summarizing the [rationale by Dennis Ritchie](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/4.0BSD_newsys_sys1.c.html):

- The caller doesn't have to worry whether a program to execute is a shell script or a native binary.
- The script itself specifies what interpreter to use, instead of the caller.
- The kernel uses the script name in logs.

Pathless shebangs would require either to augment the kernel to access environment variables and process `PATH`, or to have the kernel execute a userspace program that performs the PATH lookup. The first method requires adding a disproportionate amount of complexity to the kernel. The second method is already possible with a [`#!/usr/bin/env` shebang](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29608/why-is-it-better-to-use-usr-bin-env-name-instead-of-path-to-name-as-my).

¹  <sub>If you put a relative path, it's interpreted relatively to the current directory of the process (not the directory containing the script), which is hardly useful in a shebang.</sub>

Comment: No, the kernel does not require an absolute path in `execve` nor in the shebang though it makes little sense to have a relative path in a shebang.

Comment: For anyone that's curious about how "shebang re-routes the execve call internally":  It's actually part of a generic mechanism for running interpreters on executables that need them.  Dynamically-linked ELF executables are "interpreted" by `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` (see `ldd` output).  Linux makes it fully generic: `binfmt` support (since 2.1.43) lets you register interpreter-path / magic-number-or-file-extension pairs. You can have PE32 `.exe`s invoke `wine` when you run them, Java class and jar files invoke `java`, etc. etc.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env -S [shebang] was required for me running node without knowing its path (using nvm - which places it in a different location than I originally expected).

Comment: -S is only available since coreutils 8.30. See https://gitlab.com/gnuwget/wget/commit/b3f86f90cc5b3d3d1c2d6f720818fda9486108ec.

Answer (score 19):

There's more going on than meets the eye. `#!` lines get interpreted by the Unix or Linux kernel, `#!` isn't an aspect of shells.  This means that `PATH` doesn't really exist at the time the kernel decides what to execute.

The most common way to deal with not knowing which executable to run, or to call `perl` in a portable fashion or similar, is to use `#!/usr/bin/env perl`.  The kernel executes `/usr/bin/env`, which inherits a `PATH` environment variable. `env` finds (in this example) `perl` in `PATH` and uses the `execve(2)` system call to get the kernel to run the `perl` executable.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ strace sleep 1
execve("/usr/bin/sleep", ["sleep", "1"], [/* 99 vars */]) = 0
```

The conversion to the full path is done by the shell (more general: in userspace). The kernel expects a file name / path it can access directly.

If you want the system find your executable by looking through the PATH variable, you can rewrite your shebang as `#!/usr/bin/env EXEC`.

But also in this case it's not the kernel who does the search.

Comment: *The conversion to the full path is done by the shell* Thanks, although... is the example supposed to illustrate that? As I see it, the shell is just running `strace` (converted to `/usr/bin/strace` at some point) with 2 arguments.