# What is the difference in these two bash environments?

Tags: bash, shell-script, executable, shebang

I notice that with `bash` scripts, some people use a different 
[shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) to the one that I'm used to putting at the top of my own.

Can someone simplify the difference between these two? I use the `#!/bin/bash` one all the time.

```
#!/bin/bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Comment: see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29608/why-is-it-better-to-use-usr-bin-env-name-instead-of-path-to-name-as-my and take note of what it says about passing arguments to the interpreter.  IMO using `/usr/bin/env` like this is an abuse of the `env` program perpetrated mostly by the python community because they can't manage interpreter and library versioning properly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `#!/usr/bin/env bash` results in the script using whatever bash is found first in `$PATH`.

While it is common for bash to be located at `/bin/bash`. There are cases where it is not (different operating systems). Another potential use is when there are multiple bash shells installed (newer version at an alternate location like `/usr/local/bin/bash`).

Doing `#!/usr/bin/env bash` just takes advantage of a behavior of the `env` utility.
The `env` utility is normally used for manipulating the environment when calling a program (for example; `env -i someprog` to wipe the environment clean). However by providing no arguments other than the program to execute, it results in executing the specified program as found in `$PATH`.

---

Note that there are both advantages and disadvantages to doing this.

The advantages are as mentioned earlier, in that it makes the script portable if bash is installed in a different location, or if `/bin/bash` is too old to support things the script is trying to do.

The disadvantage is that you can get unpredictable behavior. Since you're at the mercy of the user's `$PATH`, it can result in the script being run with a version of bash that has different behavior than what the script expects.