# Which shell interpreter runs a script with no shebang?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, zsh, shebang

Suppose the default shell for my account is zsh but I opened the terminal and fired up bash and executed a script named `prac002.sh`, which shell interpreter would be used to execute the script, zsh or bash? Consider the following example:

```
papagolf@Sierra ~/My Files/My Programs/Learning/Shell % sudo cat /etc/passwd | grep papagolf
[sudo] password for papagolf: 
papagolf:x:1000:1001:Rex,,,:/home/papagolf:/usr/bin/zsh
# papagolf's default shell is zsh

papagolf@Sierra ~/My Files/My Programs/Learning/Shell % bash
# I fired up bash. (See that '%' prompt in zsh changes to '$' prompt, indicating bash.)

papagolf@Sierra:~/My Files/My Programs/Learning/Shell$ ./prac002.sh 
Enter username : Rex
Rex
# Which interpreter did it just use?
```

**EDIT : ** Here's the content of the script

```
papagolf@Sierra ~/My Files/My Programs/Learning/Shell % cat ./prac002.sh 
read -p "Enter username : " uname
echo $uname
```

Comment: What does the script say at the top?

Comment: @MichaelHomer : Nothing. I just edited the question to add the content of script. The script has executable permission.

Comment: If you want to use the current shell, dot source it, as in `. prac002.sh`, assuming your script is in the current dir.

Comment: @thecarpy: I guess I didn't get it. I'm running the script using `./prac002.sh`. What part of it do you want me to change?

Comment: Run `. ./prac002.sh` and it will run with the current shell, that is, dot (`.`), space ( ) followed by the path of your script. It is called dot-sourcing your script. ;-)

Comment: @thecarpy: Thanks for the tip. I didn't know that!!!

Comment: Similar: [Why is the first line comment of .sh file necessary?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/84179)

Comment: Also: [shell scripts are still working without #!(sha-bang line)](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/50425) though the accepted answer is plain wrong

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of [Writing shell scripts that will run on any shell (using multiple shebang lines?)](https://superuser.com/q/502984/354511) — see [grawity’s ‘‘amazingly thorough’’ answer](https://superuser.com/q/502984/354511#503009).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Because the script does not begin with a `#!` shebang line indicating which interpreter to use, [POSIX says that](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01_01):

> If the [`execl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execl.html) function fails due to an error equivalent to the [ENOEXEC] error defined in the System Interfaces volume of POSIX.1-2008, **the shell shall execute a command equivalent to having a shell invoked with the pathname resulting from the search as its first operand**, with any remaining arguments passed to the new shell, except that the value of "$0" in the new shell may be set to the command name. If the executable file is not a text file, the shell may bypass this command execution. In this case, it shall write an error message, and shall return an exit status of 126.

That phrasing is a little ambiguous, and different shells have different interpretations.

In this case, **Bash will run the script using itself**. On the other hand, if you ran it from zsh instead, **zsh would use `sh`** (whatever that is on your system) instead.

You can verify that behaviour for this case by adding these lines to the script:

```
echo $BASH_VERSION
echo $ZSH_VERSION
```

You'll note that, from Bash, the first line outputs your version, while the second never says anything, no matter which shell you use.

- If your `/bin/sh` is, say, `dash`, then neither line will output anything when the script is executed from zsh or dash.
- If your `/bin/sh` is a link to Bash, you'll see the first line output in all cases.
- If `/bin/sh` is a *different version* of Bash than you were using directly, you'll see different output when you run the script from bash directly and from zsh.

The [`ps -p $$` command from rools's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/373228/73093) will also show useful information about the command the shell used to execute the script.

Comment: I have even seen `csh` be used when `#!` was missing. I certainly consider the absence of `#!` in the beginning of a script to be an error. And having this workaround in shells probably does more harm than good. But it's good that you point out what POSIX says about it, I certainly wasn't aware of that.

Comment: @kasperd It’s certainly not an error, it’s the *only* standard kind of script. If it’s a POSIX sh script no-shebang is even the *most portable* way to write it (you don’t know where a compatible shell lives). Running it with csh would be non-conforming, though.

Comment: the ZSH_VERSION does not always return something, the solution proposed below (i.e. to use `realpath /proc/$$/exe` is the most portable solution.

Comment: @efx `$ZSH_VERSION` *should* **always** be undefined in this context. `/proc` is non-standard, as is `realpath`, so `realpath /proc/$$/exe` is not portable at all, though it will work on e.g. many (but not all) systems with GNU coreutils. The answer to the question at hand is that there is no specific implementation you can generally rely upon.

Answer (score 11):

Since the file is not of any of the types of executable recognised by the system, and assuming you've got the permission to execute that file, the `execve()` system call will typically fail with a `ENOEXEC` (*not an executable*) error.

What happens then is up to the application and/or library function used to execute the command.

That can be for instance a shell, the `execlp()`/`execvp()` libc function.

Most other applications will use either of those when they run a command. They will invoke a shell for instance by way of the `system("command line")` libc function which will typically invoke `sh` to parse that command line (the path of which can be determined at compile time (like `/bin/sh` vs `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh` on Solaris)), or invoke the shell stored in `$SHELL` by themselves like `vi` with its  `!` command, or `xterm -e 'command line'` and many other commands (`su user -c` will invoke the user's login shell instead of `$SHELL`).

Generally, a shebang-less text file that doesn't start with `#` is considered as a `sh` script. Which `sh` it is will vary though.

`execlp()`/`execvp()`, upon `execve()` returning `ENOEXEC` will typically invoke `sh` on it. For systems that have more than one `sh` because they can conform to more than one standard, which `sh` it is will be typically determined at compilation time (of the application using `execvp()`/`execlp()` by linking a different blob of code which refers to a different path to `sh`). For instance, on Solaris, that will be either `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh` (a standard, POSIX `sh`) or `/bin/sh` (the Bourne shell (an antiquated shell) on Solaris 10 and older, ksh93 in Solaris 11).

When it comes to shells, there's a lot of variation. `bash`, AT&T `ksh`, the Bourne shell will typically interpret the script themselves (in a child process unless `exec` is used) after having simulated a `execve()`, that is unset all the unexported variables, closed all the close-on-exec fds, removed all the custom traps, aliases, functions... (`bash` will interpret the script in `sh` mode). `yash` will execute itself (with `sh` as `argv[0]` so in `sh` mode) to interpret it.

`zsh`, `pdksh`, `ash`-based shells will typically invoke `sh` (the path of which determined at compilation time).

For `csh` and `tcsh` (and the `sh` of some early BSDs), if the first character of the file is `#`, then they will execute themselves to interpret it, and `sh` otherwise. That goes back to a pre-shebang time where `csh` did recognise `#` as comments but not the Bourne shell, so the `#` was a hint that it was a csh script.

`fish` (at least version 2.4.0), just returns an error if `execve()` fails (it doesn't attempt to treat it as a script).

Some shells (like `bash` or AT&T `ksh`) will first try to heuristically determine whether the file is probably meant to be a script or not. So you may find that some shells will refuse to execute a script if it's got a NUL character in the first few bytes.

Also note that if `execve()` fails with ENOEXEC but the file does have a shebang line, some shells do try to interpret that shebang line themselves.

So a few examples:

- When `$SHELL` is `/bin/bash`, `xterm -e 'myscript with args'` will have `myscript` interpreted by `bash` in `sh` mode. While with `xterm -e myscript with args`, `xterm` will use `execvp()` so the script will be interpreted by `sh`.
- `su -c myscript` on Solaris 10 where `root`'s login shell is `/bin/sh` and `/bin/sh` is the Bourne shell will have `myscript` interpreted by the Bourne shell.
- `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk 'BEGIN{system("myscript")'` on Solaris 10 will have it interpreted by `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh` (same for `/usr/xpg4/bin/env myscript`).
- `find . -prune -exec myscript {} \;` on Solaris 10 (using `execvp()`) will have it interpreted by `/bin/sh` even with `/usr/xpg4/bin/find`, even in a POSIX environment (a conformance bug).
- `csh -c myscript` will have it interpreted by `csh` if it starts with `#`, with `sh` otherwise.

All in all, you can't be sure what shell will be used to interpret that script if you don't know how and by what it will be invoked.

In any case, `read -p` is `bash`-only syntax, so you'll want to make sure that script is interpreted by `bash` (and avoid that misleading `.sh` extension). Either you know the path of the `bash` executable and use:

```
#! /path/to/bash -
read -p ...
```

Or you can try and rely on a `$PATH` lookup of the `bash` executable (assuming `bash` is installed) by using:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
read -p ...
```

(`env` is almost ubiquitously found in `/usr/bin`). Alternatively, you can make it POSIX+Bourne compatible in which case you can use `/bin/sh`. All systems will have a `/bin/sh`. On most of them it will be (for the most part) POSIX-compatible, but you may still find now and then a Bourne shell there instead.

```
#! /bin/sh -
printf >&2 'Enter a user name: '
read user
printf '%s\n' "$user"
```

Answer (score 4):

To check which shell is used, you can run the following script.

```
ps -p $$
echo -n "The real shell is: "
realpath /proc/$$/exe
```

On my computer I get

```
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
13718 pts/16   00:00:00 sh
The real shell is: /usr/bin/bash
```

even if my default shell is *zsh*. It uses *bash* since on my machine, *sh* command is implemented by *bash* and *zsh* picks *sh* if no shebang is specified.