# Does "sh" have to be in the "/bin" directory?

Tags: linux, shell, posix

I have read that POSIX compliant operating systems (for example: Linux) must have the `sh` shell.

But is it required for `sh` to be in the `/bin` directory, or can it be in any directory?

Comment: You can always use a symlink as `/bin/sh`, in most cases on linux, it's already a symlink to `bash`. It's just that lots of scripts use hardcoded `/bin/sh`

Comment: Now that you have the answer that it can live anywhere it wants, you may ask yourself: how can you then portably write a shebang line for `sh`? And the answer is: shebang isn't part of POSIX either, so the problem doesn't even present itself.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Yes, it's sometimes surprising how many of the things we think of as "standard" Unix features are not actually required by POSIX.

Comment: Whether or not you use a shebang is independent of whether the path `/bin/sh` must exist on a POSIX system.

Comment: At least on Ubuntu-derived systems, `/bin/sh` is a link to `dash`. On the BSDs, `/bin/sh` is its not a link but a separate executable, and certainly not `bash`.

Answer (score 24):

[POSIX only mandates the `/dev` and `/tmp` directories to exist](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap10.html#tag_10_01), and the `/dev/null`, `/dev/tty`, and `/dev/console` files. The standard utilities must exist, but there is no particular location specified. There may not be a `/bin` at all, and if there is it may not contain a `sh`, and if it does that may not be a POSIX `sh`.

You can get a valid `PATH` variable that includes the POSIX tools, including `sh`, with the [`getconf` command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getconf.html):

```
$ PATH=$(getconf PATH)
$ sh
```

This can be useful on, for example, Solaris, where [the default `sh` is not POSIX-compatible](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5165/sh-1.html), but a compliant `sh` is provided and accessible in that way (because [Solaris is a certified Unix](https://www.opengroup.org/openbrand/register/brand3585.htm)). `getconf PATH` will include `/usr/xpg4/bin` at the front, which contains POSIX `sh` and a number of other required tools ([including useless ones like `cd`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38808/why-is-cd-not-a-program/38819#38819)).

Comment: Re Solaris: ...unless you're running a Solaris "small server" installation, which omits many of the POSIX tools.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/360359/135943

Comment: "Useless" ones? I'd rather call them redundant.

Comment: so how is getconf found?

Comment: @MukeshSaiKumar a stand-alone ‘cd’ command cannot ever work

Comment: Well, it'll "work" only for a value of working that, say, tests whether you *can* change to a directory, but doesn't actually leave the process that called it there. That's more functionality than none at all, though.

Comment: @Joshua Hopefully it’s already in your path. In practice it is, because that’s useful, and there’s no historic command with the same name to be shadowed.

Comment: Note that on Solaris, you will get _different_ values of `PATH` back depending on which `getconf` you call. Which one you call (for example `/usr/xpg4/bin/getconf`) will determine what type of standard shell utilities you get access to.

Answer (score 12):

No, it is not required for `sh` to be in `/bin`.  It explicitly cites `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, and `/usr/xpg4/bin` as possible locations.  The POSIX spec only requires that `sh` be in the PATH.

The [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html) states:

> Applications should note that the standard PATH to the shell cannot be
>   assumed to be either `/bin/sh` or `/usr/bin/sh`, and should be determined
>   by interrogation of the PATH returned by getconf PATH, ensuring that
>   the returned pathname is an absolute pathname and not a shell
>   built-in.
>
> For example, to determine the location of the standard sh utility:
>
> `command -v sh`
>
> On some implementations this might return:
>
> `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh`

Answer (score 3):

As others here have said, this is not strictly required for POSIX compliance.

But arguably compatibility with existing software is far more important (after all, the purpose of POSIX is to have certain things work on all conforming operating systems) and if an OS does not provide sh at `/bin/sh`, that will break some things.

Most obviously, scripts with `#!/bin/sh` rely on this path being standardized. This is not required to work; [POSIX doesn't even require that `#!` lines are supported, although it mentions that such functionality is common](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html):

> Another way that some historical implementations handle shell scripts is by recognizing the first two bytes of the file as the character string "#!" and using the remainder of the first line of the file as the name of the command interpreter to execute.

But if that isn't supported, a lot of existing software will break or require additional work to port.