# Script doesn't work with shebang "/usr/bin/env sh", but does with "/usr/bin/env bash" though sh points to bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script which logs the performance of various programs passed to it as arguments, to help me choose the most performant one. The relevant snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
function cal_perf () {
        real_t=0
        user_t=0
        sys_t=0
        for (( trial=1 ; trial<=$3 ; ++trial )) ; do
                shopt -s lastpipe
                /usr/bin/time -f '%e:%S:%U' $1 $2 |& IFS=":" read real sys user
                real_t=$(echo "$real + $real_t" | bc)
                user_t=$(echo "$user + $user_t" | bc)
                sys_t=$(echo "$sys + $sys_t" | bc)
        done
        real_t=$(echo "scale=2 ; $real_t / $3" | bc)
        user_t=$(echo "scale=2 ; $user_t / $3" | bc)
        sys_t=$(echo "scale=2 ; $sys_t / $3" | bc)
        printf "%s\t%d\t%.2f\t%.2f\t%.2f\n" $2 $3 $real_t $user_t $sys_t >> timings_$(date '+%Y%m%d')
}

# main
printf "program\t#trials\treal_time_am\tuser_time_am\tsys time_am\n" > timings_$(date '+%Y%m%d')
translator=$1
shift
while [ $# -gt 1 ] ; do cal_perf $translator $1 ${!#} ; shift ; done
```

It's supposed to be run on the command line as follows:

```
perf <translator_progam> <list_of_programs_to_compare> <number_of_trials>
```

...for instance: suppose I want to compare the performances of `xip.py, foo.py, bar.py, bas.py, qux.py`--the net content of the working directory--and run them each for 50 times before generating the stats; I'd invoke the script as:

```
perf python *py 50
```

I think I am missing something obvious here, but when I invoke this script as `bash $HOME/bin/perf ...` everything works as intended. However, the following two invocations fail (error attached):

1. `perf ...`
2. or even placing it in the working directory and invoking as `./perf ...`

[image]

changing the shebang to `/usr/bin/env bash` solves this problem, but  `/usr/bin/sh` points to `/usr/bin/bash` on my system.

Comment: The C-style `for` loop is a bashism, it doesn't exist in `sh`.

Comment: True that, but should that be a concern when `/usr/bin/sh` is a symlink to `/usr/bin/bash`?

Comment: Are you sure `/usr/bin/env sh` resolves to `/usr/bin/sh`?

Comment: I think I missed your point. What're the irrelevant ones here?

Comment: @choroba yes, that's correct.

Comment: Related (but not necessarily a duplicate) - [Running a shell script when "/bin/sh" points to "/bin/bash"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/416234/100397)

Comment: This is documented in https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-POSIX-Mode: "When invoked as `sh`, Bash enters POSIX mode after reading the startup files."

Comment: Regardless of whether `sh` is actually bash or not, _why_ do you want to use `sh` when you _know_ you use bash-specific functionality?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error comes when `$3` expands to the empty string in

```
for (( trial=1 ; trial<=$3 ; ++trial ))
```

Bash *does* support `for (( .. ))` even in POSIX mode, so that in itself is not the issue. In this particular case, the problem is the `${!#}` expansion used when calling the function. It can be parsed in two ways.

In a standard shell, it's the prefix-removal operation `${var#word}` applied to the special parameter `!`, with an empty string to remove. Removing the empty string doesn't do anything, but for sake of an example, we could remove one character:

```
$ dash -c 'sleep 123 & echo $! ${!#?};'
27920 7920
```

But in Bash, `${!#}` is taken as the indirect expansion `${!var}`, using `$#` as the "pointer", giving the last positional parameter.

Bash does support the indirect expansion even in POSIX mode, but there, it treats that corner case in a more standard-conforming way. The [documentation actually says this](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html):

> 31. While variable indirection is available, it may not be applied to the ‘#’ and ‘?’ special parameters.

Now, since `$!` contains the PID of the last background process, but the script doesn't start any, the standard meaning gives just the empty string. Leading to the eventual error.

You could also use `"${@: -1}"` to get the last positional parameter in Bash. It's not standard either, but does work in POSIX mode.

Anyway, in general, if you want to use non-POSIX features supported by Bash, like `(( .. ))`, `${!var}`, `${var:n:m}`, run `bash`, not `sh`. You'll save yourself the trouble of dealing with the incompatibilities.

Comment: Note that of `(( .. ))`, `${!var}`, `${var:n:m}`, only `${!var}` comes from bash. The other two come from ksh. `${!var}` in ksh has the almost opposite meaning.

Answer (score 21):

You are running the script with `sh` as the interpreter, but you are using `bash` features. Even assuming that `sh` points to `bash`, you still cannot do this as `bash` disables many of its custom features when asked to run as `sh`.

One solution is to declare the script correctly. You're using `bash` features so declare it as a `bash` script.

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Or, if you need continue with a dependency on `env`,

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Another option is to remove the `bash`-specific syntax.

In either case, don't forget to ensure variables are enclosed inside double-quotes when you use them. For example, if one of your unquoted variables (including script parameters) contains a space it will be split by the shell into two or more words.

Comment: @puwlah you should also revisit the `/usr/bin/time ... | read real sys user` construct, as it will not set any of those three variables. (Well, technically it will, but the shell will immediately discard them.) Generally you should also ensure your variables are inside double-quotes when you use them.

Comment: (1) thanks for pointing out that `bash` disables many of its custom features when asked to run as `sh`.
(2) `word splitting` wasn't a concern here, so `quoting` wasn't necessary: only place there's a risk of undesired word splitting is the expansion of `$2` (files_names); which I am controlling. However, a good practice in general, agreed.... [1/2]

Comment: (3) The `some_comand | read some variable(s)` construct isn't universally useless. it won't be an issue with `#!/[usr/]bin/[env ]bash` because using `bash` as the interpreter allows for  the (preceding) `shopt -s lastpipe` solution which executes the `read` to the right (of the `stderr pipeline`) in the current shell environment, and not a subshell. So, the variables assigned there can be accessed subsequently. [2/2].

Comment: @puwlah answer modified - I'd missed your `shopt -s lastpipe`