# Error when running ((x++)) as root

Tags: root

I make bash script temp.sh with the following content:

```
age=0;
((age++));
```

When I run it as a normal user, it runs fine.

But when i run it as root I get error:

./temp.sh: 4: ./temp.sh: age++: not found

Why is that?

Comment: Are you using the same shell and settings for both users ? What's the output of `echo $SHELL` as non-root and as root ?

Comment: its /bin/bash both as normal user and as root. But Jesse answered.

Comment: The exact output of `./temp.sh: 4: ./temp.sh: age++: not found` is generated by dash running an script called as `./temp.sh`. That seems to be your root shell.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the absence of a hashbang, `/bin/sh` is likely being used.  Some POSIX shells do support the `++` and `--` operators, and `((...))` for arithmetic evaluations, but are not required to.

Since you have not included a hashbang in your example I will assume you are not using one and therefore your script is likely running in a POSIX shell that does not support said operator.  Such a shell would interpret `((age++))` as the `age++` command being run inside two nested sub-shells.

When you run it as a "normal" user it is likely being interpreted by bash or another shell that does support said operator and `((...))`.

Related: [Which shell interpreter runs a script with no shebang?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/373229/237982)

To fix this you can add a hashbang to your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
age=0
((age++))
```

Note: You do not need to terminate lines with `;` in bash/shell.

---

To make your script portable to all POSIX shells you can use the following syntax:

```
age=$((age + 1))
age=$((age += 1))
```

Comment: Or use the standard `sh` syntax: `age=$((age + 1))`, or `: "$((age += 1))"`

Comment: The exact output of `./temp.sh: 4: ./temp.sh: age++: not found` is generated by dash running an script called as `./temp.sh`. That seems to be the root shell.

Answer (score 1):

Another old time answer (or highly multiple platform compatible) is:

```
 age=`expr $age + 1`
```