# How to define global functions in zsh (macOS) that are available in scripts?

Tags: shell-script, zsh, function

Since macOS 10.15 (Catalina) the default shell has changed from bash to zsh. One of the things I'm running into is I cannot get my own global functions working. I used to export these from .bash_profile but zsh doesn't seem to know the concept of exporting functions.

Say I have this:

`function greet { echo "Hello $1, how are you today" }`

If I then run `hello RocketNuts` on the shell, it says `Hello RocketNuts, how are you today`. So far so good.

Now I want to make this function global **so that it's also available in scripts**.

I have tried:

- putting it in `.zshrc`
- putting it in `.zshenv`

I also tried creating a subdir `~/myfunctions` and a file called `~/myfunctions/greet` which contains:

```
function greet { echo "Hello $1, how are you today" }
greet "$@"
```

and then in either `~/.zshrc` or `~/.zshenv` I add:

```
fpath=( ~/myfunctions "${fpath[@]}" )
autoload -Uz greet
```

However, none of these methods make the `greet` function available in scripts.

From the shell, they all work fine. With either method, I can invoke the `greet` function manually on the shell.

But if I have a file `test.sh` which does `greet Somebody` and run that, it always says "greet: command not found".

How do I get this working in zsh?

Comment: Your forgot to post the content of `greet.sh`.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' They have `~/myfunctions/greet` there. Does it have to have a `.sh` filename suffix?

Comment: @Kusalananda The suffix is not relevant, but the _full_ content of the file is. Possibly even the way the script is executed. But at the very least the file contents.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' it's there in my post, after "a file called ~/myfunctions/greet which contains:" (the contents are just those 2 lines).

Comment: Oh ok. So that's not a zsh script: without a shebang line, it's an sh script. That's why I asked for the whole file.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' How do you mean without a shebang line? Isn't it just supposed to be interpreted by the default shell interpreter, which in this case is zsh? Anyway note that the script IS executed, because I can manually use `greet` on the shell just fine.

Comment: @RocketNuts The default shell interpreter is `sh`, not `zsh`. Zsh is the default _login_ shell on recent macOS versions, but this has nothing to do with shell scripts. This is explained in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373223/which-shell-interpreter-runs-a-script-with-no-shebang