# Bash logon script strange behavior

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, scripting, login

I am currently making a honeypot which will record all user input once they login successfully through SSH.

Here's how it works: I have my honeypot user `admin`'s default shell set to a bash script:

`admin:x:1001:1001::/home/admin:/home/admin/HoneyPot/spawner.sh`

The `spawner.sh` script will go ahead and launch an `except` script and record the output using `script`.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/admin/HoneyPot/template/

pwd
script -c "./script.exp" -t 2> timing.log -a output.session #start recording session, execute except script
echo "we should not get here"
```

Here are the first few lines of `script.exp`:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
#
# This Expect script was generated by autoexpect on Mon Oct  5 13:55:35 
# boilerplate comments and code:

set force_conservative 0  ;# set to 1 to force conservative mode even if
              ;# script wasn't run conservatively originally
if {$force_conservative} {
    set send_slow {1 .1}
    proc send {ignore arg} {
        sleep .1
        exp_send -s -- $arg
    }
}

# start of my code

set timeout -1
spawn emulator #emulator is a simh emulator executable. not a shell script.
...
interact
```

When I run the script using `./template.sh` as `admin` using `bash`, the script runs perfectly fine. However, when I login using `su`, this happens:

```
austin@ubuntu:~$ su admin
Password: 
/home/admin/HoneyPot/template
Script started, file is output.session
/home/admin/HoneyPot/template
Script started, file is output.session
/home/admin/HoneyPot/template
Script started, file is output.session
/home/admin/HoneyPot/template
Script started, file is output.session
/home/admin/HoneyPot/template
Script started, file is output.session
/home/admin/HoneyPot/template
...
```

Why is my bash script not working with the user's shell set to it? There are no recursive calls inside my script, and the `script` command should be blocking!

And just in case anyone is worried, this machine has no outgoing network connectivity. It can only receive SSH connections. Yes, I know that a user can break out of this. This is being ran in a VM.

Comment: can you add the first few lines of script.exp? is it or a sub script missing a shebang?

Comment: @laktak as requested, thanks for looking at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using a script without a shebang somewhere.

See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/373229/46158):

> If the execl() function fails due to an error equivalent to the [ENOEXEC] error defined in the System Interfaces volume of POSIX.1-2008, the shell shall execute a command equivalent to having a shell invoked with the pathname resulting from the search as its first operand, with any remaining arguments passed to the new shell, except that the value of "$0" in the new shell may be set to the command name. If the executable file is not a text file, the shell may bypass this command execution. In this case, it shall write an error message, and shall return an exit status of 126.

in your `spawner.sh` add `echo "$@"` to get more hints.

OK, so the answer is more complicated but this should help. In `spawner.sh` add this a the top:

```
if [[ $1 == -c ]]; then
    exec bash "$@"
fi
```

Comment: When I run spawner.sh manually from bash shell, that echo statement returns a blank line. When I run it via logging in, it returns "-c ./script.exp". Gah!

Comment: Thanks for the update. This works perfectly.