# Shell script error ONLY when using watch command

Tags: shell-script, watch

I'm trying to create a shell script that reads and writes to certain text files on two second intervals. When I run the script by itself (without watch), it works perfectly fine. However, when I run it using `watch -n 2 ./feedcmd.sh`, I'm given this error: `./feedcmd.sh: 2: ./feedcmd.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`.

I've tried adding an extra pair of parentheses around that phrase, but still no luck.

Here's my shell script:

```
$(tmux capture-pane -t "$tes3-server" -pS 32768 > one.txt)
output=$(comm -23 <(sort one.txt) <(sort two.txt))
len=`expr "$output" : '.*'`
if [ "$len" -gt 0 ]; then
       $(echo "$output" > fin.txt)
       $(cat one.txt > two.txt)
       $(echo 0 > done.d)
fi
echo "done"
```

Comment: Your script doesn't appear to have a "shebang" - `watch` is likely executing it using /bin/sh, which doesn't support process substitutions like `<(command)`

Comment: I see. I think I'll just put the script in a loop and use sleep to run it in intervals. Thank you. Also, what exactly do you mean by a "shebang"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)

Answer (score 0):

Your script doesn't have a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)). The `watch` command is likely executing it using `/bin/sh`, which doesn't support the `<(command)` process substitution construct<sup>1</sup>:

```
$ cat myscript
cat <(echo foo)

$ watch -n 2 ./myscript
```

==>

```
Every 2.0s: ./myscript                                                                   t400s: Sun Mar  7 09:09:04 2021
./myscript: 1: ./myscript: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

whereas

```
$ cat myscript
#!/bin/bash
cat <(echo foo)

$ watch -n 2 ./myscript
```

==>

```
Every 2.0s: ./myscript                                                                   t400s: Sun Mar  7 09:07:32 2021
foo
```

---

1. more precisely, it passes the command to `sh -c ' ... '` which then follows the rules outlined in [Which shell interpreter runs a script with no shebang?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373223/which-shell-interpreter-runs-a-script-with-no-shebang)