# BASH script w/ functions won't run on startup

Tags: bash

I have a BASH script that runs fine in terminal. But when I try to get it to run on startup, nothing happens. It seems related to the fact that the script uses functions. When I break the commands out of functions, it works as expected on startup. Any thoughts on why? Here is an example, but any arbitrary code in the function creates the same issue:

```
 #!/bin/bash 

say-stuff () {
    
    notify-send Stuff "Here is some stuff." 

}

say-stuff
```

Comment: How are you setting it to run on startup and where is `notify-send` being set?

Comment: Is `notify-send` available in `$PATH` in the environment where the script is being executed? Are you expecting to be able to notify a particular user with a graphical pop-up at boot time? How are you running your script at startup and what does the script output (error messages etc.; you can see these if you redirect the error stream to a file)?

Comment: I just put that `notify-send` command there for a minimal working example. But any command has the same issue. The script is located in ~/user/.local/bin and I am using the "Startup Applications" under Pop!_OS to run the script. And it works as expected if I 1) run it from terminal or 2) alter the script to remove the functions and leave the commands. It seems that the functions are at issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a space before the shebang in your script - which breaks the file magic:

```
$ printf '#!/bin/bash\n' | file -
/dev/stdin: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
```

but

```
$ printf ' #!/bin/bash\n' | file -
/dev/stdin: ASCII text
```

This causes the XDG autostart mechanism to fall back to executing the script with /bin/sh, in which `say-stuff` isn't a valid function name:

```
$ sh -c 'say-stuff () { echo "stuff"; }'
sh: 1: Syntax error: Bad function name
```

You can see this happening if you run `xdg-autostart` in an interactive terminal with a minimal .desktop file:

```
$ cat ~/.config/autostart/say-stuff.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]

Type=Application

Name=say-stuff

Exec=say-stuff
```

then

```
$ xdg-autostart 2>&1 | grep -A3 say-stuff
** Message: 18:23:33.620: xdg-autostart.vala:39: Processing /home/steeldriver/.config/autostart/say-stuff.desktop file.
** Message: 18:23:33.627: xdg-autostart.vala:94: Launching: say-stuff (say-stuff.desktop)
** Message: 18:23:33.627: xdg-autostart.vala:39: Processing /etc/xdg/autostart/nm-tray-autostart.desktop file.
/home/steeldriver/.local/bin/say-stuff: 3: Syntax error: Bad function name
** Message: 18:23:33.646: xdg-autostart.vala:94: Launching: nm-tray (nm-tray-autostart.desktop)
** Message: 18:23:33.646: xdg-autostart.vala:39: Processing /etc/xdg/autostart/upg-notifier-autostart.desktop file.
** Message: 18:23:33.655: xdg-autostart.vala:94: Launching: /usr/libexec/lubuntu-update-notifier/lubuntu-upg-notifier.sh (upg-notifier-autostart.desktop)
```

It "works" when you execute the script directly because

- `say-stuff` is a legal function name in bash; and
- your interactive shell is bash, and that causes the script with the invalid shebang to also run in bash

See also [Which shell interpreter runs a script with no shebang?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373223/which-shell-interpreter-runs-a-script-with-no-shebang)

Comment: This was indeed the issue, @steeldriver. Thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

Jobs run through `cron`, or startup scripts aren't run in the same runtime environment that you have on your desktop. Startup scripts are run as `root`. None of your `PATH` changes, or other environment  variable settings from `~/.bashrc` are automatically propagated to  your `cron` job. For example, there's no `$DISPLAY`, so GUI programs need special treatment (read `man xhost`).

One can set environment variables for all one's `cron` jobs in the `crontab` file
Read `man 5 crontab`.

Look at the results of  `echo "=== id ===";id;echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments.

An easy way is to store the commands in a `bash` script, and execute it from your terminal session, saving the output, then, execute the script from the "other" environment, saving the output. Compare the saved outputs using `diff`.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "=== id ===";id
echo "=== set ===";set
echo "=== env ===";env | sort
echo "=== alias ===";alias`
```

Comment: Waltinator, does this explain why the command runs outside of a function, but not in one at startup?

Comment: @Linter It would potentially explain why `notify-send` (or _any command that needs access to a graphical interface_) would fail to run when there is no GUI running. I'm noting that you still have not updated your question with information about how you run the script.

Comment: First, from `man notify-send`:  `DESCRIPTION
       With notify-send you can send desktop notifications to the user via a notification daemon
       from the command line.  These notifications can be used to inform the user about an  event
       or display some form of information without getting in the user's way.
`, so you have to find a "notification daemon". Second,  do you understand that `$PATH` is a per-process, colon-separated list of directories to search for programs to run? And, @Kusalananda I have updated my answert