# How does the system decide which shell runs a script without a shebang line?

Tags: shell-script, shell, shebang

I have this "script" on my Arch Linux system:

```
$ cat ~/scripts/foo.sh
ps -hp $$
```

It will simply run `ps` on its own PID. But the script has no shebang line. I was expecting that in the absence of a specific shebang, the system would run this either using whatever interactive shell I used to launch it, or using whatever I have set as `$SHELL`. However, I see that it does change depending on which shell I am running but it isn't consistent:

1. If I launch it from a bash session, it is run by bash:

   ```
   $ ps -hp $$ 
   1267979 pts/15   Ss     0:00 /bin/bash
   $ foo.sh
   1276346 pts/15   00:00:00 bash
   ```
2. If I launch it from a zsh session, it is run by `sh` (which is `bash` on my system):

   ```
   % ps -hp $$ 
   1279855 pts/15   S      0:00 zsh
   % foo.sh
   1280006 pts/15   S+     0:00 sh /home/terdon/scripts/foo.sh
   ```
3. If I launch it from an `sh` session, it is run by `sh` again:

   ```
   $ ps -hp $$
   1281052 pts/15   S      0:00 sh
   $ foo.sh
   1281296 pts/15   S+     0:00 sh
   ```
4. If I launch it from an `tcsh` session, it is run by `sh` again:

   ```
   > ps -hp $$
   1281968 pts/15   S      0:00 -csh
   > foo.sh
   1282148 pts/15   S+     0:00 /bin/sh /home/terdon/scripts/foo.sh
   ```
5. If I launch it from a `dash` session, it is run by `sh` yet again

   ```
   $ ps -hp $$
   1282803 pts/15   S      0:00 dash
   $ foo.sh
   1283404 pts/15   S+     0:00 /bin/sh /home/terdon/scripts/foo.sh
   ```

So it looks like bash is the only shell that will run a script using itself when the script is launched from a bash session and all the others I tested will use `sh` instead. This isn't related to whether `/bin/sh` is `bash` or another shell. I also tested on an Ubuntu system whose `/bin/sh` is `dash` and got the same behavior: bash would run the script using itself, `dash` and `zsh` would run it using `sh`.

On both my Arch and the Ubuntu system mentioned above, my `SHELL` variable is set to `/bin/bash` and my user's entry in `/etc/passwd` has `/bin/bash` as my default shell.

Questions:

- Who controls this? Is it the kernel or the shell? Is this a bash feature (i.e. bash will use itself in the absence of a shebang)? Something else?
- Why do the shells behave differently? Why do I have so many different formats in the output of `ps`? I see `sh /home/terdon/scripts/foo.sh` and `sh` alone, and `/bin/sh /home/terdon/scripts/foo.sh`. What's going on here? I realize these are all equivalent, but it's surprising to see so many different ways of launching the same essential job.

Comment: Apologies for the hammer, I think my answer there answers most of your questions here.

Comment: No apology needed, @StephenKitt, it's nice to be on the receiving end for once! However, maybe I'm just being dense, but I don't see where your answer explains why launching a shebang-less script from bash makes it run in bash while all other shells seem to use sh, nor why each shell results in a different ps output with some reporting `sh script.sh`, others reporting `sh` and others reporting `/bin/sh script.sh`. Is it just down to how each shell launches its subprocesses? And is any of this user specific (are `$SHELL` or the user's passwd entry relevant) or is it always `/bin/sh`?

Comment: There's some quite detailed discussion at [Which shell interpreter runs a script with no shebang?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373223/which-shell-interpreter-runs-a-script-with-no-shebang)

Comment: Ah, thanks @steeldriver, that is closer to what I was looking for, I'll add it as a dupe target.

Comment: Indeed, thanks @steeldriver, that is closer and I think it covers everything, including the `ps` variations.

Comment: @StephenKitt sometimes thread titles stick in my brain for some reason ;)