# #!/usr/bin/env foo #!vs /usr/bin/foo

Tags: scripting, path, shebang

Which of the above forms is "better" for running bash, python etc. scripts? Why can't I just do `#!$(which foo)`? Is it neccecery to specify full path to `env`? I gather from [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/93646/20506) answer, that the path `/usr/bin/env` is set in stone for all *nix-es, much more than `/usr/bin/python3` for example. Is that so?

Answer (score 2):

You can’t just write `#!$(which foo)` because that line is interpreted by the kernel, which does not understand complex syntaxes like `$()`.

The kernel does not search for the command in the `PATH` environment variable. That’s why you have to specify the full path to the command.

The use of `/usr/bin/env` is a clever hack used to search the command in the `PATH`. Even if there is a `/usr/bin/python3` program, you may for example have installed a more recent version of Python in a different path, for example in you home directory.

Comment: Ahaa, so `$()` is a shell feature. As well as searching the path, consequently I can't just write `#!python3`. What about the cross-platform issue. Do we get `/usr/bin/env` on MacOS? FreeBSD? QNX?

Comment: Searching the `PATH` is not exactly a shell feature; it is a `libc` feature. That’s only a guess, but `/usr/bin/env` might be required by the POSIX standard.

Comment: You can't use #!$(which foo) because shell expansion does not occur for comments... as in #! (a comment)... This is by specific design. There is no "better" or "best" way to set your interpreter. I tend to use #!/usr/bin/env perl + #!/usr/bin/env ffmpeg, because I build these nightly, against latest source. So in general, you'll use /usr/bin/env when you have multiple copies of a program in your $PATH + you'd like to take the highest precedence version (one appearing first in your $PATH variable).

Comment: @DavidFavor It does not matter that it’s a comment, it matters that it is a special kernel feature.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Are you sure it is a feature of the shell? I just gave it a try, and could also run that shell script through /usr/bin/env…