# Bash script command line argument to upper case

Tags: bash, shell-script

If I can do this in my bash shell:

```
$ STRING="A String"
$ echo ${STRING^^}
A STRING
```

How can I change my command line argument to upper case?

I tried:

```
GUARD=${1^^}
```

This line produces *Bad substitution* error for that line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's start with this test script:

```
$ cat script.sh 
GUARD=${1^^}
echo $GUARD
```

This works:

```
$ bash script.sh abc
ABC
```

This does not work:

```
$ sh script.sh abc
script.sh: 1: script.sh: Bad substitution
```

This is because, on my system, like most debian-like systems, the default shell, `/bin/sh`, is *not* bash.  To get bash features, one needs to explicitly invoke bash.

The default shell on debian-like systems is `dash`.  It was chosen not because of features but because of speed.  It does not support `^^`. To see what it supports, read `man dash`.

Comment: … and you can "explicitly invoke bash" for a script (i.e., specify that a script should be run by bash) by putting it in the "she-bang" (the first line of the script).  `#!/bin/bash` will work on many systems, `#!/usr/bin/bash` will work on others, and `#!/usr/bin/env bash` should work on all systems that have bash (if it's in your search path).  See [Does the shebang determine the shell which runs the script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87560/23408) and [Why is it better to use “#!/usr/bin/env NAME” instead of “#!/path/to/NAME” as my shebang?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29608/23408)

Answer (score 5):

With `tr` command:

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $@ | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'
```

Check:

```
$ bash myscript.sh abc 123 abc
ABC 123 ABC
```

Answer (score 0):

`typeset -u VAR=VALUE` works too