# What is wrong with the code?

Tags: shell-script

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=1 ;i<=3;i++))
do
echo "Enter gallon used(gal):"
read gal
echo "Enter Miles Obtained(mil):"
read mil
mileage=`echo $mil / $gal |bc`
echo "scale=4; $mileage " | bc
c=`echo $c + $mileage | bc`
echo "$c + $mileage = $c"
echo
done
```

Comment: And what's the reported error?

Comment: For one you are trying to use a variable in it's own declaration and then echoing that the variable + another equals itself.

Comment: Yes, the problem is in this line: `c=\`echo $c + $mileage | bc\``; `echo $c + $mileage | bc` is (obviously) run before the shell assigns its output to `$c`, so `$c` is undeclared while running `echo $c + $mileage | bc`

Comment: I am trying to calculate the mileage for 3 input and get the average. plus the mileage only come out as integer. I need decimals.

Comment: By the way, your conceptual algorithm is flawed — the average of a series of mileage values is generally not the average mileage. For example, if you use 4 gallons driving 80 miles up a mountain (→ 80/4 = 20 mpg) and then you use 1 gallon while driving/coasting 80 miles back down the mountain (→ 80/1 = 80 mpg), your average mileage is not (20+80)/2=50, it is (80+80)/(4+1)=160/5=32.

Answer (score 1):

Is `c` your accumulator? Set it to zero to start with, then you will not get a syntax error in line 10.

You get an integer result because there is no operation in line 9.
Merge lines 8 and 9 to

```
mileage=$(echo "scale=4; $mil / $gal" | bc)
```

and then `mileage` will have a decimal result.

You do not do anything useful with `$c` and fail to print it after the loop.

Comment: Thanks that was helpful, now i have decimal result. I need to work on accumulating.

Comment: And yes c is suppose to be my accumulator

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Above, get the path to BASH from the environment.
# Below, you could just set the total mileage here.
total_mileage=0

# Below, start from zero and count up for the three loops.
for ((i=0; i<3; i++)); do
    # Below, use `-n` to prevent the new line.
    # It's ok to use descriptive variable names.
    # echo -n "Enter gallons used: "
    # Below, quote variables.
    # read "gallons"

    # Using the suggestion for `read` from @roaima :
    read -p "Enter gallons used  : " "gallons"

    # Use a regular expression (regex). Here, a number with optional decimal:
    while [[ ! $gallons =~ ^[+-]?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$ ]]; do
        echo "Please enter a number or [CTRL]+[C] to exit."
        read -p "Enter gallons used  : " "gallons"
    done

    # echo -n "Enter miles obtained: "
    # read "miles"

    # Using the suggestion for `read` from @roaima :
    read -p "Enter miles obtained: " "miles"
    while [[ ! $miles =~ ^[+-]?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$ ]]; do
        echo "Please enter a number or [CTRL]+[C] to exit."
        read -p "Enter miles obtained: " "miles"
    done

    # Below, backticks are antiquated.
    mileage=$(echo "scale=4; ($miles) / ($gallons)" | bc)
    echo "Mileage: $mileage"

    total_mileage=$(echo "scale=4; $total_mileage + $mileage" | bc)

done

average_mileage=$(echo "scale=4; ($total_mileage) / ($i)" | bc)
echo "Average mileage is $average_mileage"
```

See these, too:

- [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)
- [What's the difference between $(stuff) and `stuff`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/whats-the-difference-between-stuff-and-stuff)
- [Why is it better to use “#!/usr/bin/env NAME” instead of “#!/path/to/NAME” as my shebang?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29608/why-is-it-better-to-use-usr-bin-env-name-instead-of-path-to-name-as-my)
- [How to do integer & float calculations, in bash or other languages/frameworks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40786/80216)

Comment: #### I did this###   #!/bin/bash
c=0
for ((i=1 ;i<=3;i++))
do
echo "Enter gallon used(gal):"
read gal
echo "Enter Miles Obtained(mil):"
read mil
mileage=`echo "scale=6; $mil / $gal" |bc`
echo "The miles/gallon of a tankful was: $mileage"
c=`echo "scale=6; $c + $mileage" |bc`
done
echo 
average=`echo "scale=6; $c / 3" |bc`
echo "The overall Average miles/gallon attained was :$average"

Comment: What about when i want to exit the program when the user input -1?

Comment: And thanks, i like the way you comment on the program.

Comment: You're running bash. Consider `read -p "Enter miles obtained: " miles`, etc.

Comment: thanks, that part is working well now. But I still having difficulty terminating the program when user input -1

Comment: Yes, you should always quote all *references* to shell variables (e.g., `"$gallons"` and `"$miles"`) unless you have a good reason not to, and you’re sure you know what you’re doing. But you don’t need to quote their *names* when you’re setting them; `read gallons` is perfectly fine and safe. … … … … … … P.S. Why do you divide by 1 in `bc`?