# Syntax error unexpected end of file

Tags: linux, shell-script, fedora, virtual-machine

I have written a shell script which allows me to create a user and assign them to a group but I keep getting the error `line 19: syntax error: unexpected end to file`

What am I doing wrong? Would it be possible someone could help me re structure the code to eliminate this problem.

Here is my shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash
username="U"
group="G"
while [ $username"U" ] >/dev/null 2>&1;
read -p "Please input the username you would like to generate"
if
  id -U $username >/dev/null 2&1;
echo 'User already exists"
while [ $group >dev/null 2>&1; 

echo "group exists"

else
    groupadd $group
fi
```

Comment: Dear Poster, Please put your code into edit page and select it, Then press CTRL+K.

Comment: Please dont post screenshots of text, paste the *actual text*...

Comment: Your `while [ condition ]; do...` statements need closure with `done`. `if [ condition ]` statement needs to be flowed by `then` keyword. It is not implied.

Comment: Put the script in here, surrounded by lines containing three backticks like ```.

Comment: The indentation of your code is awful. Proper indentation would make it a lot easier to see what is wrong, but @MelBurslan has a lot of it.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish with this script ? Can you briefly explain in words ? It sounds like you are trying to create usernames, which were input from the keyboard and check if they already exist. If not create them. Is this the gist of it ? Or there is something else to it ? If it is, your logic is not correct, as well as your use of bash syntax leaves a lot to be desired. Although I have to give it to you at least for trying, unlike too many people here expecting someone else do all the work.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate this. My task is to  write a script that creates new users and assigning them to groups.

Comment: Do you want your script to take username and groups as arguments? Or to ask the user for input?

Comment: Ask the user to input also I'm not fimilar what you mean by arguments.

Comment: Hint: look at the colors in your question. Tip: use an editor with syntax-based coloring.

Comment: Arguments are specified on the command line itself, not prompted and asked for by the script.  In your case, you might use `./myscript username groupname` and then in your script use `"$1"` for the username and `"$2"` for the group name.  Note the use of double-quotes around the `$1` and `$2` variables.  it's good practice to (almost) always quote your variables (except in certain special cases which there's no need to go into now), **especially** if the variable's value is provided by a user in any way (e.g. via command-line args or prompted input).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something you could use.  It will remain in the loop until a new non existing user has been created.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

anotherUser() {
   read -p "Add another user? [y/n]" yn
   if [[ $yn = *[yY]* ]]; then
      checkUser
   fi
   exit
}
checkUser() {
while :
   do
      read -p "Enter user: " userName
      if id $userName >/dev/null
         then echo "User exists"
         anotherUser
      else
         adduser "$userName"
         printf "User %s has been added\n" "$userName"
         exit
      fi
   done
}
checkUser
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks for taking the time to help me out. Instead of it keep looping would it be possible if you could add something like do you want to create another user y/n and if the user inputs n it will terminate.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I haven't built any checking though, but that's left as exercise for the student! ;)

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by checking? Do you mean running the script and seeing if it executes?

Comment: I mean the user input.  You never know if a user will put a `_` or a ` ` <-- space etc.  Anyways, you now should have a bit of an idea of what this script does.

Comment: Oh right. For example I should include something like if user inputs integer ask the question again.

Comment: @L.Docherty correct. Integers in usernames on *nix are allowed though but they may not start with an integer. E.g  `12345` as a username is not allowed where `abc1234` is allowed.  You just run the script, test it a bit and modify it to your needs.

Comment: '#!/usr/bin/env bash' Quick question why did you use env bash?

Comment: @L.Docherty this makes sure that the script looks at whatever shell is availiable on your path. It is more portable. If you are running a recent version of ubuntu or fedora or any other distribution, `#!/bin/bash`  would work as well.

Comment: I got another error. The first one is line 19: unexpected E0F while looking for match and line 26 syntax error unexpected end of file.

Comment: More accurately, `#!/usr/bin/env bash` is a dreadful mistake promoted by the python and ruby communities because they don't care that it breaks the ability to pass command-line options to the interpreter, or that it doesn't fix the rare problem of not knowing the exact path of the interpreter (bash or whatever), it just shifts the problem to not knowing the exact path of `env`, and causes other problems.  See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29608/why-is-it-better-to-use-usr-bin-env-name-instead-of-path-to-name-as-my for arguments for and against using `env` on the `#!` line of a script

Answer (score 0):

You have to change via `$?` variable. It stores the return value of last command:

```
id -u $username > /dev/null 2>&1 ;
if [[ "$?" -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "username already exists."
```

If it equals 1, it doesn't exist.
BTW, your blocks are very dirty.... Use the following link:
[Indentation (typesetting)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_%28typesetting%29)
Also close your blocks.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of the indentations being poor but I'm trying my best. I have visited the hyperlink webpage but since I'm new at this I'm still very confused. Would you mind making some adjustments and pointing me in the right direction with my code please?

Comment: @PersianGulf: you don't have to do this I think. `if id -u $username >/dev/null 2>&1; then` should work.

Comment: @L. Levrel , I didn't use `id` command in if statement, please reread my code.

Comment: @L.Docherty , You can use Advanced bash script by TLDP : http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ ,Even you can download it's pdf from tldp.org

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, I will read this now.

Comment: @PersianGulf: That's exactly what I mean. IMHO it is simpler to put the command in the `if` statement. YMMV

Comment: @L.Docherty  reality sorry, I think I answered you via bashism.

Comment: @PersianGulf No problem, could you help me with this please? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/271809/shell-script-creating-and-assign-to-groups-advice-needed-on-my-script.