# Desktop Entry Requires "bash" in Exec Value

Tags: bash, shell-script, executable

I recently began messing with Desktop Entries in order to run some scripts at Gnome startup.

I've read through some freedesktop documentation, as well as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247706/start-script-when-gnome-starts-up) on creating a startup script.  I currently have a desktop entry working on startup, but it is not behaving in the way I was made to understand it should.

Some system info: this is CentOS7 running on VirtualBox in Windows

This is my desktop entry:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=fixres
GenericName=Resolution Fixer
Comment=Changes resolution to 1920x1080
Exec=bash /home/detroitwilly/scripts/fixres.sh
Terminal=false
Type=Application
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

The script being executed uses xrandr to add a new resolution mode and apply it to my virtual display.

Now, the first line in the script has the shebang `#!/bin/bash`.  My understanding is that if the shebang is on the first line of the script, I shouldn't need to specify `bash` in the `Exec=` line of the desktop entry.  Note that if I remove `bash` from the `Exec=` line, the application will not run.

I've also verified that `/bin` is in my `$PATH` variable, so I should automatically have access to `bash`.

Any ideas as to why i need to prepend the path to my script with `bash`?

Thanks!

Comment: I am confused, are these comments to the answer, bellow? (if so then it is better to attach them to the answer) or to a deleted comment?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor the answer below was submitted after the comments above were posted

Comment: So what are they commenting about, they make no sense without a context. It may be better to remove them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two portions required to execute a BASH script directly:

1. the shebang
2. the executable bit

The shebang should look as follows.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

(Using `env` is a best practice. It can also be written as the full path, e.g. `#!/bin/bash`.)

Then set the executable bit as follows.

```
chmod +x /home/detroitwilly/scripts/fixres.sh
```

Comment: It may be better to do `#!/bin/bash` (pronounced “hash bash slash bin slash bash”) , as it is more stable, not prone to changes in users PATH variable.

Comment: There are advantages and dis-advantages: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29620/4778