# Getting a parameter from a config file in FreeBSD

Tags: bash, freebsd, configuration

I want to make a bash file that reads a parameter from a config file. In Debian based linux it works fine by:

**my.config:**

```
MYVARIABLE=12345
```

**my.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash

source my.config
echo $MYVARIABLE
```

But I am not able to achieve this in FreeBSD. Do you have any idea?

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: `source: not found` I tried also a full path to the config file, but no change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not supply any errors or what you have done. This then leaves us guessing:

1. Bash is not installed by default. You might need to add it yourself:

   `pkg install bash`
2. As with Debian you need to make the script executable:

   `chmod +x my.sh`
3. The first line of your script should point to the location of bash. It is not located in `/bin` by default. You can make it work using a link but I would prefer to change the first line of your script to:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env bash

   source my.config
   echo $MYVARIABLE
   ```

The above will make you script OS agnostic. Or you can use the explicit path:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

source my.config
echo $MYVARIABLE
```

## Why?

See [Why is it better to use “#!/usr/bin/env NAME” instead of “#!/path/to/NAME” as my shebang?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29608/why-is-it-better-to-use-usr-bin-env-name-instead-of-path-to-name-as-my)