# Adding #!something doesnt look at PATH

Tags: linux, bash, path

In Linux adding #!/bin/bash is telling the the executable to execute with bash.

I was wondering, why is this specified in full path? I would expect that since bin is in a path specified in PATH it would find it just by adding #!bash

This is not really an inconvenience, just curious. Thanks

Comment: It's the way `#!` is defined.

Answer (score 1):

The way `#!` works is that it must be followed by the full pathname of the interpreter. If you want to search `$PATH` the commonly used construction is `#!/usr/bin/env` <interpreter>, for example

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
```

will look for `perl` in `$PATH`. For more information for why this works see the manual page for [env](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man1/env.1.html) and the [nice discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12736/how-does-usr-bin-env-know-which-program-to-use/12751#12751) under "[How does /usr/bin/env know which program to use?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12736/how-does-usr-bin-env-know-which-program-to-use)" on this forum.